# SELECT all N between @min and @max

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to select all numbers N (integers) between @min and @max
Is there any way to achieve that without using a loop of some sort?

Example:
Let's say @min = 5, @max = 9

I need the following values returned by my SQL query: 5,6,7,8,9

(I'm using MSSQL 2005)

Thanks!!

EDIT:
This is a solution using a custom function, which works fine.
But it seems too much effort having to loop through all numbers manually.
So the question is still, whether it's achievable without a loop.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetAllNBetween
(    
    @Min int,
    @Max int
)
RETURNS @N TABLE(n int)
AS
BEGIN
    WHILE @Min <= @Max
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @N VALUES(@Min)
        SET @Min = @Min + 1
    END
    RETURN
END
```

To be used like this:

```
SELECT * FROM GetAllNBetween(5, 9)
```

Comment: To clarify: I don't have a table with all N anywhere.

Comment: why do you need to do this in sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query (as suggested by @Eric)

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY so1.id) from sysobjects so1,sysobjects
```

Returns the numbers between 1 and ~3000, on my mostly empty test database. You can add another level of sysobjects to get an insane number of rows. Then it's a simple matter of filtering this

Answer (score 2):

Well I don't see the point why you don't want to use a loop, but you can use a recursion instead.

```
DECLARE @min INT
DECLARE @max INT

SET @min = 5;
SET @max = 12;

WITH Nbrs ( n ) AS (
    SELECT @min UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 + n FROM Nbrs WHERE n < @max
)
SELECT n FROM Nbrs
OPTION ( MAXRECURSION 500 )
```

It will generate a table with all values. Generating a string list out of this shouldn't be too hard ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the between keyword. Here is the example.

```
select *
  from tableName
 where e_id between (SELECT min(e_id) FROM tableName a)
                and (SELECT max(e_id) FROM tableName a)
```

And if you know min and max then directly put those instead of nested query.

Comment: Well the problem is that there is no table that exists with the entries. So 'tableName' doesn't exists in my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
DECLARE @min int, @max int
SELECT @Min=5,@Max= 9

SELECT TOP (@Max-@Min+1) @Min-1+row_number() over(order by t1.number) as N
FROM master..spt_values t1 
    CROSS JOIN master..spt_values t2
```

OUTPUT:

```
N
--------------------
5
6
7
8
9

(5 row(s) affected)
```

see this previous question: [What is the best way to create and populate a numbers table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393951/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-and-populate-a-numbers-table)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
declare @min int

set @min= (select 5)

 declare @max int

set @max=(select 9)

select * from table

where id between @min and @max
```

Comment: Well the problem is that there is no table that exists with the entries. So 'table' doesn't exists in my scenario.

Comment: Look at my answer using the function. That's what I'm getting at. Except without the function ;)

Answer (score 0):

Can you make use of this function row_number()? It's new in Mssql 2005.

Also I just found out that you can also do this in ms sql 2005:

```
select *
  from dbo.GetTableOfSequentialIntegers(100)
 where number between 5 and 9
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any answers with a CTE (Common Table Expression), so here's one:

```
WITH RECURSIVE integers(n)
AS (
  SELECT @min
  UNION SELECT n + 1 FROM integers WHERE n < @max
) SELECT n FROM integers
```

Comment: I wasn't even aware of CTEs. I looks very promising. Except I can't get the query you provided to work. Are you able to provide a complete sample, please?