# SQL Conver commaseperated list into different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, csv, multiple-columns

I want to convert a comma seperated string list into different columns.
Eaxh time the number of columns( items in the list) will be different . SO need to do this dynamically.
Example.
(1,2,3,4)
(1,2)
(1,2,3)
Conver first row into 4 columns, second into 2 and third into 3 columns.

I have these values in rows in one table I am using XML code to make it in string.
Here is my code to convert rows into string

select  barcode,
    stuff((SELECT 
 ', ' + glce_score
 FROM #GLCE_Scores c1 
 where(c1.barcode = c.barcode)
order by barcode,Strand_Sort,glce_sort
 FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as name into #temp1
FROM #GLCE_Scores c 
 group by barcode
order by barcode
Now I have to convert that string into columns.
In short I have to convert rows into columns.

Comment: Sorry for the invalid and unnecessary rollback, I'm apparently illiterate today.  That said, you need to show what you've tried so far.

Comment: You would need to write your own function to do that  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200125/t-sql-convert-one-column-containining-delimiter-to-many-columns

Comment: I have update my question  http://stackoverflow.com/users/334849/littlebobbytables