# Calculate business hours between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, math

How can I calculate business hours between two dates?
For example we have two dates; 01/01/2010 15:00 and 04/01/2010 12:00
And we have working hours 09:00 to 17:00 in weekdays
How can I calculate working hours with sql?

Comment: I assume you don't need to take national holidays etc into account?

Comment: ... and what of lunch breaks, tea breaks etc?

Comment: Yes, I dont take national holidays and breaks.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Baran's answer fixed and modified for SQL 2005

SQL 2008 and above:

```
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Baran Kaynak (modified by Kodak 2012-04-18)
-- Create date: 14.03.2011
-- Description: 09:30 ile 17:30 arasındaki iş saatlerini hafta sonlarını almayarak toplar.
-- =============================================
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[WorkTime] 
(
    @StartDate DATETIME,
    @FinishDate DATETIME
)
RETURNS BIGINT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Temp BIGINT
    SET @Temp=0

    DECLARE @FirstDay DATE
    SET @FirstDay = CONVERT(DATE, @StartDate, 112)

    DECLARE @LastDay DATE
    SET @LastDay = CONVERT(DATE, @FinishDate, 112)

    DECLARE @StartTime TIME
    SET @StartTime = CONVERT(TIME, @StartDate)

    DECLARE @FinishTime TIME
    SET @FinishTime = CONVERT(TIME, @FinishDate)

    DECLARE @WorkStart TIME
    SET @WorkStart = '09:00'

    DECLARE @WorkFinish TIME
    SET @WorkFinish = '17:00'

    DECLARE @DailyWorkTime BIGINT
    SET @DailyWorkTime = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @WorkStart, @WorkFinish)

    IF (@StartTime<@WorkStart)
    BEGIN
        SET @StartTime = @WorkStart
    END
    IF (@FinishTime>@WorkFinish)
    BEGIN
        SET @FinishTime=@WorkFinish
    END
    IF (@FinishTime<@WorkStart)
    BEGIN
        SET @FinishTime=@WorkStart
    END
    IF (@StartTime>@WorkFinish)
    BEGIN
        SET @StartTime = @WorkFinish
    END

    DECLARE @CurrentDate DATE
    SET @CurrentDate = @FirstDay
    DECLARE @LastDate DATE
    SET @LastDate = @LastDay

    WHILE(@CurrentDate<=@LastDate)
    BEGIN       
        IF (DATEPART(dw, @CurrentDate)!=1 AND DATEPART(dw, @CurrentDate)!=7)
        BEGIN
            IF (@CurrentDate!=@FirstDay) AND (@CurrentDate!=@LastDay)
            BEGIN
                SET @Temp = @Temp + @DailyWorkTime
            END
            --IF it starts at startdate and it finishes not this date find diff between work finish and start as minutes
            ELSE IF (@CurrentDate=@FirstDay) AND (@CurrentDate!=@LastDay)
            BEGIN
                SET @Temp = @Temp + DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartTime, @WorkFinish)
            END

            ELSE IF (@CurrentDate!=@FirstDay) AND (@CurrentDate=@LastDay)
            BEGIN
                SET @Temp = @Temp + DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @WorkStart, @FinishTime)
            END
            --IF it starts and finishes in the same date
            ELSE IF (@CurrentDate=@FirstDay) AND (@CurrentDate=@LastDay)
            BEGIN
                SET @Temp = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartTime, @FinishTime)
            END
        END
        SET @CurrentDate = DATEADD(day, 1, @CurrentDate)
    END

    -- Return the result of the function
    IF @Temp<0
    BEGIN
        SET @Temp=0
    END
    RETURN @Temp

END
```

SQL 2005 and below:

```
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Baran Kaynak (modified by Kodak 2012-04-18)
-- Create date: 14.03.2011
-- Description: 09:30 ile 17:30 arasındaki iş saatlerini hafta sonlarını almayarak toplar.
-- =============================================
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[WorkTime] 
(
    @StartDate DATETIME,
    @FinishDate DATETIME
)
RETURNS BIGINT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Temp BIGINT
    SET @Temp=0

    DECLARE @FirstDay DATETIME
    SET @FirstDay = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @StartDate))

    DECLARE @LastDay DATETIME
    SET @LastDay = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @FinishDate))

    DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME
    SET @StartTime = @StartDate - DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @StartDate), 0)

    DECLARE @FinishTime DATETIME
    SET @FinishTime = @FinishDate - DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @FinishDate), 0)

    DECLARE @WorkStart DATETIME
    SET @WorkStart = CONVERT(DATETIME, '09:00', 8)

    DECLARE @WorkFinish DATETIME
    SET @WorkFinish = CONVERT(DATETIME, '17:00', 8)

    DECLARE @DailyWorkTime BIGINT
    SET @DailyWorkTime = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @WorkStart, @WorkFinish)

    IF (@StartTime<@WorkStart)
    BEGIN
        SET @StartTime = @WorkStart
    END
    IF (@FinishTime>@WorkFinish)
    BEGIN
        SET @FinishTime=@WorkFinish
    END
    IF (@FinishTime<@WorkStart)
    BEGIN
        SET @FinishTime=@WorkStart
    END
    IF (@StartTime>@WorkFinish)
    BEGIN
        SET @StartTime = @WorkFinish
    END

    DECLARE @CurrentDate DATETIME
    SET @CurrentDate = @FirstDay
    DECLARE @LastDate DATETIME
    SET @LastDate = @LastDay

    WHILE(@CurrentDate<=@LastDate)
    BEGIN       
        IF (DATEPART(dw, @CurrentDate)!=1 AND DATEPART(dw, @CurrentDate)!=7)
        BEGIN
            IF (@CurrentDate!=@FirstDay) AND (@CurrentDate!=@LastDay)
            BEGIN
                SET @Temp = @Temp + @DailyWorkTime
            END
            --IF it starts at startdate and it finishes not this date find diff between work finish and start as minutes
            ELSE IF (@CurrentDate=@FirstDay) AND (@CurrentDate!=@LastDay)
            BEGIN
                SET @Temp = @Temp + DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartTime, @WorkFinish)
            END

            ELSE IF (@CurrentDate!=@FirstDay) AND (@CurrentDate=@LastDay)
            BEGIN
                SET @Temp = @Temp + DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @WorkStart, @FinishTime)
            END
            --IF it starts and finishes in the same date
            ELSE IF (@CurrentDate=@FirstDay) AND (@CurrentDate=@LastDay)
            BEGIN
                SET @Temp = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartTime, @FinishTime)
            END
        END
        SET @CurrentDate = DATEADD(day, 1, @CurrentDate)
    END

    -- Return the result of the function
    IF @Temp<0
    BEGIN
        SET @Temp=0
    END
    RETURN @Temp

END
```

Comment: I have a question here, @Temp returns the difference in minutes only?

Comment: If you know 1 hour = 60 minutes and so on, you can easily convert it :)

Comment: Just so you know there is a bug in this fine solution.  The second if block needs a check to see if the number is negative and if so to exclude it.  Otherwise the time after end of work will subtract time.

Comment: I added the following lines to fix the bug that JStead mentions above: `IF (@FinishTime<@WorkStart)
    BEGIN
        SET @FinishTime=@WorkStart
    END` and `IF (@StartTime>@WorkFinish)
    BEGIN
        SET @StartTime = @WorkFinish
    END`.  These can be added right before the declaration of @CurrentDate.

Comment: I have added Dave's code to the answer, thanks for input

Comment: Maybe a CLR UDF then?

Comment: @mathiasflorin, please have a look at my answer. The formula is very simple and fast. It does assume that the given start and end date/times are during the business hours, though.

Comment: Thanks for the code.We've used this in production but I needed to come up with a faster solution as we have to recalculate the function over millions of records if business hours change. Find below a version without a loop and start/end dates in/out of business hours.

We have this requirement for some SCD1 scenarios where we do not want to keep SCD2 history.

Comment: How could you in the best way exclude a one hour lunch between 12-1pm (working day is eight hours between 8am-5pm)?

Comment: To make this work to include weekends I'd need to remove this part?
`BEGIN IF (DATEPART(dw, @CurrentDate)!=1 AND DATEPART(dw, @CurrentDate)!=7)`

Comment: @Rockshah Work days with weekends is equal to all days and simple DATEDIFF should work for you then

Comment: @Kodak I still need the working hours bit (regardless of day) but manipulated this to work for weekends

Answer (score 21):

I know this is post is very old but here is a function I wrote recently to calculate Business Hours/Minutes between any two events. It also takes into account any holidays which must be defined in a table.

The function returns the interval in minutes - you can divide by 60 to get hours as required.

This has been tested on SQL Server 2008. Hope it helps someone.

```
Create Function GetWorkingMin(@StartDate DateTime, @EndDate DateTime, @Country Varchar(2)) Returns Int
AS
Begin
    Declare @WorkMin int = 0   -- Initialize counter
    Declare @Reverse bit       -- Flag to hold if direction is reverse
    Declare @StartHour int = 9   -- Start of business hours (can be supplied as an argument if needed)
    Declare @EndHour int = 17    -- End of business hours (can be supplied as an argument if needed)
    Declare @Holidays Table (HDate DateTime)   --  Table variable to hold holidayes

    -- If dates are in reverse order, switch them and set flag
    If @StartDate>@EndDate 
    Begin
        Declare @TempDate DateTime=@StartDate
        Set @StartDate=@EndDate
        Set @EndDate=@TempDate
        Set @Reverse=1
    End
    Else Set @Reverse = 0

    -- Get country holidays from table based on the country code (Feel free to remove this or modify as per your DB schema)
    Insert Into @Holidays (HDate) Select HDate from HOLIDAY Where COUNTRYCODE=@Country and HDATE>=DateAdd(dd, DateDiff(dd,0,@StartDate), 0)

    If DatePart(HH, @StartDate)<@StartHour Set @StartDate = DateAdd(hour, @StartHour, DateDiff(DAY, 0, @StartDate))  -- If Start time is less than start hour, set it to start hour
    If DatePart(HH, @StartDate)>=@EndHour+1 Set @StartDate = DateAdd(hour, @StartHour+24, DateDiff(DAY, 0, @StartDate)) -- If Start time is after end hour, set it to start hour of next day
    If DatePart(HH, @EndDate)>=@EndHour+1 Set @EndDate = DateAdd(hour, @EndHour, DateDiff(DAY, 0, @EndDate)) -- If End time is after end hour, set it to end hour
    If DatePart(HH, @EndDate)<@StartHour Set @EndDate = DateAdd(hour, @EndHour-24, DateDiff(DAY, 0, @EndDate)) -- If End time is before start hour, set it to end hour of previous day

    If @StartDate>@EndDate Return 0

    -- If Start and End is on same day
    If DateDiff(Day,@StartDate,@EndDate) <= 0
    Begin
        If Datepart(dw,@StartDate)>1 And DATEPART(dw,@StartDate)<7  -- If day is between sunday and saturday
            If (Select Count(*) From @Holidays Where HDATE=DateAdd(dd, DateDiff(dd,0,@StartDate), 0)) = 0  -- If day is not a holiday
                If @EndDate<@StartDate Return 0 Else Set @WorkMin=DATEDIFF(MI, @StartDate, @EndDate) -- Calculate difference
            Else Return 0
        Else Return 0
    End
    Else Begin
        Declare @Partial int=1   -- Set partial day flag
        While DateDiff(Day,@StartDate,@EndDate) > 0   -- While start and end days are different
        Begin
            If Datepart(dw,@StartDate)>1 And DATEPART(dw,@StartDate)<7    --  If this is a weekday
            Begin
                If (Select Count(*) From @Holidays Where HDATE=DateAdd(dd, DateDiff(dd,0,@StartDate), 0)) = 0  -- If this is not a holiday
                Begin
                    If @Partial=1  -- If this is the first iteration, calculate partial time
                    Begin 
                        Set @WorkMin=@WorkMin + DATEDIFF(MI, @StartDate, DateAdd(hour, @EndHour, DateDiff(DAY, 0, @StartDate)))
                        Set @StartDate=DateAdd(hour, @StartHour+24, DateDiff(DAY, 0, @StartDate)) 
                        Set @Partial=0 
                    End
                    Else Begin      -- If this is a full day, add full minutes
                        Set @WorkMin=@WorkMin + (@EndHour-@StartHour)*60        
                        Set @StartDate = DATEADD(DD,1,@StartDate)
                    End
                End
                Else Set @StartDate = DATEADD(DD,1,@StartDate)  
            End
            Else Set @StartDate = DATEADD(DD,1,@StartDate)
        End
        If Datepart(dw,@StartDate)>1 And DATEPART(dw,@StartDate)<7  -- If last day is a weekday
            If (Select Count(*) From @Holidays Where HDATE=DateAdd(dd, DateDiff(dd,0,@StartDate), 0)) = 0   -- And it is not a holiday
                If @Partial=0 Set @WorkMin=@WorkMin + DATEDIFF(MI, @StartDate, @EndDate) Else Set @WorkMin=@WorkMin + DATEDIFF(MI, DateAdd(hour, @StartHour, DateDiff(DAY, 0, @StartDate)), @EndDate)
    End 
    If @Reverse=1 Set @WorkMin=-@WorkMin
    Return @WorkMin
End
```

Comment: I'm afraid there is a small bug in this code. If your StartDate falls on a weekend or a holiday, it adds 1 full day the start date to account for it. So, if your start is at 1pm on Sunday, it will start counting from 1pm Monday instead of the StartHour on Monday. To correct this, change the two identical lines that read: "Else Set (at)StartDate = DATEADD(DD,1,(at)StartDate)" to this: "Else Set (at)StartDate = DATEADD(HOUR, (at)StartHour, CAST(CAST(DATEADD(DD,1,(at)StartDate) AS DATE) AS DATETIME))"

Answer (score 9):

An alternative solution from @Pavanred's, coming at things from a more data-based angle:

Create a table with all the dates you want to consider in it. For each day, set a number of working hours, like so:

```
WorkingDate Hours Comment
=========== ===== ==================
 1 Jan 2011     0 Saturday
 2 Jan 2011     0 Sunday
 3 Jan 2011     0 Public Holiday
 4 Jan 2011     8 Normal working day
 5 Jan 2011     8 Normal working day

 -- and so on, for all the days you want to report on.
```

This will take a small amount of setting up -- you can pre-populate it for weeks versus weekends automatically, then adjust for public holidays, etc, as necessary.

But, what you lose in the setting up, you gain in ease of querying:

```
SELECT
  SUM(Hours) 
FROM
  working_days 
WHERE
  WorkingDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

...and this can work out as an easier approach if you need to start adding more complicated rules for what defines a working day, or if your working hours vary depending on the day, etc.

It also makes the rules more easily "editable", as you don't need to change any actual code to change the definitions of a working day, add public holidays, etc.

Answer (score 9):

The first step would be to calculate working days, as shown in the script below:

```
DECLARE @TotalWorkDays INT, @TotalTimeDiff DECIMAL(18, 2), @DateFrom DATETIME, @DateTo DATETIME;
SET @DateFrom = '2017-06-05 11:19:11.287';
SET @DateTo = '2017-06-07 09:53:14.750';

SET @TotalWorkDays = DATEDIFF(DAY, @DateFrom, @DateTo)
    -(DATEDIFF(WEEK, @DateFrom, @DateTo) * 2)
   -CASE
                                    WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @DateFrom) = 'Sunday'
                                    THEN 1
                                    ELSE 0
                                END+CASE
                                        WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @DateTo) = 'Saturday'
                                        THEN 1
                                        ELSE 0
                                    END;
```

The second step involves getting a difference in seconds between the two dates and converting that difference into hours by dividing by 3600.0 as shown in this following script:

```
SET @TotalTimeDiff =
(
    SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND,
                   (
                       SELECT CONVERT(TIME, @DateFrom)
                   ),
                   (
                       SELECT CONVERT(TIME, @DateTo)
                   )) / 3600.0
);
```

The last part involves multiplying the output the first step above by 24 (total number of hours in a day) and then later adding that to the output of the second step:

```
SELECT(@TotalWorkDays * 24.00) + @TotalTimeDiff;
```

Finally, the complete script that can be used to create a user defined function for calculating working hours is shown below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_GetTotalWorkingHours]
(
    @DateFrom Datetime,
    @DateTo Datetime
)
RETURNS DECIMAL(18,2)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @TotalWorkDays INT, @TotalTimeDiff DECIMAL(18, 2)

SET @TotalWorkDays = DATEDIFF(DAY, @DateFrom, @DateTo)
    -(DATEDIFF(WEEK, @DateFrom, @DateTo) * 2)
   -CASE
                                    WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @DateFrom) = 'Sunday'
                                    THEN 1
                                    ELSE 0
                                END+CASE
                                        WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @DateTo) = 'Saturday'
                                        THEN 1
                                        ELSE 0
                                    END;
SET @TotalTimeDiff =
(
    SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND,
                   (
                       SELECT CONVERT(TIME, @DateFrom)
                   ),
                   (
                       SELECT CONVERT(TIME, @DateTo)
                   )) / 3600.0
);

RETURN  (SELECT(@TotalWorkDays * 24.00) + @TotalTimeDiff)

END
GO
```

The complete method is descibed in this article:
https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-calculate-work-days-and-hours-in-sql-server/

Comment: Has anyone else tried using `fn_GetTotalWorkingHours` for a date range from a Sunday to the following Saturday?

When calculating `@TotalWorkDays` should we not substract the case when `@DateTo` falls on a Saturday?

I've done a whole bunch of unit tests with this modification and it seems to work fine but happy to be corrected.

Answer (score 7):

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
DECLARE @WORKINGHOURS INT
DECLARE @Days INT
SET @StartDate = '2010/01/01'
SET @EndDate = '2010/04/01'

--number of working days
SELECT @Days = 
   (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
  -(DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 2)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @EndDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

--8 hours a day    
SET @WORKINGHOURS = @Days * 8 

SELECT @WORKINGHOURS
```

Comment: Thanks but I have hours in start and finish dates. How can we add this future in this calculation?

Comment: @Baran: Take a look at my solution

Answer (score 6):

```
    -- =============================================
-- Author:      Baran Kaynak
-- Create date: 14.03.2011
-- Description: 09:30 ile 17:30 arasındaki iş saatlerini hafta sonlarını almayarak toplar.
-- =============================================
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[WorkTime] 
(
    @StartDate DATETIME,
    @FinishDate DATETIME
)
RETURNS BIGINT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Temp BIGINT
    SET @Temp=0

    DECLARE @FirstDay DATE
    SET @FirstDay = CONVERT(DATE, @StartDate, 112)

    DECLARE @LastDay DATE
    SET @LastDay = CONVERT(DATE, @FinishDate, 112)

    DECLARE @StartTime TIME
    SET @StartTime = CONVERT(TIME, @StartDate)

    DECLARE @FinishTime TIME
    SET @FinishTime = CONVERT(TIME, @FinishDate)

    DECLARE @WorkStart TIME
    SET @WorkStart = '09:30'

    DECLARE @WorkFinish TIME
    SET @WorkFinish = '17:30'

    IF (@StartTime<@WorkStart)
    BEGIN
        SET @StartTime = @WorkStart
    END
    IF (@FinishTime>@WorkFinish)
    BEGIN
        SET @FinishTime=@WorkFinish
    END

    DECLARE @CurrentDate DATE
    SET @CurrentDate = CONVERT(DATE, @StartDate, 112)
    DECLARE @LastDate DATE
    SET @LastDate = CONVERT(DATE, @FinishDate, 112)

    WHILE(@CurrentDate<=@LastDate)
    BEGIN       
        IF (DATEPART(dw, @CurrentDate)!=1 AND DATEPART(dw, @CurrentDate)!=7)
        BEGIN
            IF (@CurrentDate!=@FirstDay) AND (@CurrentDate!=@LastDay)
            BEGIN
                SET @Temp = (@Temp + (9*60))
            END
            --IF it starts at startdate and it finishes not this date find diff between work finish and start as minutes
            ELSE IF (@CurrentDate=@FirstDay) AND (@CurrentDate!=@LastDay)
            BEGIN
                SET @Temp = @Temp + DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartTime, @WorkFinish)
            END

            ELSE IF (@CurrentDate!=@FirstDay) AND (@CurrentDate=@LastDay)
            BEGIN
                SET @Temp = @Temp + DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @WorkStart, @FinishTime)
            END
            --IF it starts and finishes in the same date
            ELSE IF (@CurrentDate=@FirstDay) AND (@CurrentDate=@LastDay)
            BEGIN
                SET @Temp = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartDate, @FinishDate)
            END
        END
        SET @CurrentDate = DATEADD(day, 1, @CurrentDate)
    END

    -- Return the result of the function
    IF @Temp<0
    BEGIN
        SET @Temp=0
    END
    RETURN @Temp

END

GO
```

Comment: does not work as expected for following dates: SELECT dbo.[WorkTime]('2012-04-18 9:30', '2012-04-18 17:31') - returns 481 instead of 480

Comment: "IF it starts and finishes in the same date" condition works on unaligned dates instead of aligned time; I will post fixed version as new answer or maybe I will try to edit one above

Comment: also above WorkStart, WorkFinish and worktime per day are desynchronized - it is better to calculate the latter dynamically - will do another edit

Answer (score 3):

The question says that public holidays should not be considered, so this answer does just that - calculates business hours taking weekends into account, but ignoring possible public holidays.

**It also assumes that the given start and end date/times are during the business hours.**

With this assumption the code doesn't care about the time when the business day starts or ends, it cares only about the total number of business hours per day. In your example, there are 8 business hours between 09:00 and 17:00. It doesn't have to be a whole number. The formula below calculates it with one minute precision, but it is trivial to make it one second or any other precision.

If you need to take public holidays into account you'd need to have a separate table which would list dates for public holidays, which may differ from year to year and from state to state or country to country. The main formula may stay the same, but you'd need to subtract from its result hours for public holidays that fall within the given range of dates.

**The formula**

```
SELECT
    DATEDIFF(minute, StartDT, EndDT) / 60.0
    - DATEDIFF(day,  StartDT, EndDT) * 16
    - DATEDIFF(week, StartDT, EndDT) * 16 AS BusinessHours
FROM T
```

---

To understand how it works let's create a table with some sample data that covers various cases:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (StartDT datetime2(0), EndDT datetime2(0));

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('2012-03-05 09:00:00', '2012-03-05 15:00:00'), -- simple part of the same day
('2012-03-05 10:00:00', '2012-03-06 10:00:00'), -- full day across the midnight
('2012-03-05 11:00:00', '2012-03-06 10:00:00'), -- less than a day across the midnight
('2012-03-05 10:00:00', '2012-03-06 15:00:00'), -- more than a day across the midnight
('2012-03-09 16:00:00', '2012-03-12 10:00:00'), -- over the weekend, less than 7 days
('2012-03-06 16:00:00', '2012-03-15 10:00:00'), -- over the weekend, more than 7 days
('2012-03-09 16:00:00', '2012-03-19 10:00:00'); -- over two weekends
```

The query

```
SELECT
    StartDT, 
    EndDT,
    DATEDIFF(minute, StartDT, EndDT) / 60.0
    - DATEDIFF(day,  StartDT, EndDT) * 16
    - DATEDIFF(week, StartDT, EndDT) * 16 AS BusinessHours
FROM @T;
```

produces the following result:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+
|       StartDT       |        EndDT        | BusinessHours |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+
| 2012-03-05 09:00:00 | 2012-03-05 15:00:00 |  6.000000     |
| 2012-03-05 10:00:00 | 2012-03-06 10:00:00 |  8.000000     |
| 2012-03-05 11:00:00 | 2012-03-06 10:00:00 |  7.000000     |
| 2012-03-05 10:00:00 | 2012-03-06 15:00:00 | 13.000000     |
| 2012-03-09 16:00:00 | 2012-03-12 10:00:00 |  2.000000     |
| 2012-03-06 16:00:00 | 2012-03-15 10:00:00 | 50.000000     |
| 2012-03-09 16:00:00 | 2012-03-19 10:00:00 | 42.000000     |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+
```

It works, because in SQL Server [`DATEDIFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) returns the count of the specified *datepart* boundaries crossed between the specified *startdate* and *enddate*.

Each day has 8 business hours. I calculate total number of hours between two dates, then subtract the number of midnights multiplied by 16 non-business hours per day, then subtract the number of weekends multiplied by 16 (8+8 business hours for Sat+Sun).

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER FUNCTION WorkTime_fn (@StartDate DATETIME, @FinishDate DATETIME)
RETURNS VARCHAR(9)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Temp BIGINT
    SET @Temp=0

    DECLARE @FirstDay VARCHAR(9)
    SET @FirstDay = CONVERT(VARCHAR(9),@StartDate, 112)

    DECLARE @LastDay VARCHAR(9)
    SET @LastDay = CONVERT(VARCHAR(9),@FinishDate, 112)

    DECLARE @StartTime VARCHAR(9)
    SET @StartTime = CONVERT(VARCHAR(9),@StartDate, 108)

    DECLARE @FinishTime VARCHAR(9)
    SET @FinishTime = CONVERT(VARCHAR(9),@FinishDate, 108)

    DECLARE @WorkStart VARCHAR(9)
    SET @WorkStart = '09:30:00'

    DECLARE @WorkFinish VARCHAR(9)
    SET @WorkFinish = '17:30:00'

    IF (@StartTime<@WorkStart)
    BEGIN
        SET @StartTime = @WorkStart
    END
    IF (@FinishTime>@WorkFinish)
    BEGIN
        SET @FinishTime=@WorkFinish
    END

DECLARE @CurrentDate VARCHAR(9)
    SET @CurrentDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(9),@StartDate, 112)
    DECLARE @LastDate VARCHAR(9)
    SET @LastDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(9),@FinishDate, 112)

WHILE(@CurrentDate<=@LastDate)
BEGIN       

        IF (DATEPART(dw, @CurrentDate)!=1 AND DATEPART(dw, @CurrentDate)!=7)
        BEGIN
              IF (@CurrentDate!=@FirstDay) AND (@CurrentDate!=@LastDay)
              BEGIN
                   SET @Temp = (@Temp + (8*60))

              END

              ELSE IF (@CurrentDate=@FirstDay) AND (@CurrentDate!=@LastDay)
              BEGIN
                SET @Temp = @Temp + DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartTime, @WorkFinish)

              END

              ELSE IF (@CurrentDate!=@FirstDay) AND (@CurrentDate=@LastDay)
              BEGIN
                SET @Temp = @Temp + DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @WorkStart, @FinishTime)

              END

              ELSE IF (@CurrentDate=@FirstDay) AND (@CurrentDate=@LastDay)
              BEGIN
                SET @Temp = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartTime, @FinishTime)

              END

             END

SET @CurrentDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(9),DATEADD(day, 1, @CurrentDate),112)

END
        Return @TEMP

END
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an inline version
Start/EndDateTime like 2015-03-16 09:52:24.000
Start/EndTime (businesshours) like 07:00:00
It is bulky but works in your select statement

I will post it in Function version as well.

```
Case when  <StartDate>= <EndDate> then 0
    When Convert(date,<StartDate>) = Convert(date,<EndDate>) Then 
         IIF( DATEPART(Dw,<StartDate>)  in(1,7)
                  or Convert(time,<StartDate>) > Convert(time,<EndTime>)
                  or Convert(time,<EndDate>) < Convert(time,<StartTime>),0, 
        DateDiff(S,IIF(Convert(time,<StartDate>) < Convert(time,<StartTime>),Convert(time,<StartTime>),Convert(time,<StartDate>))
                ,IIF(Convert(time,<EndDate>) > Convert(time,<EndTime>), Convert(time,<EndTime>), Convert(time,<EndDate>))))
    when  Convert(date,<StartDate>) <> Convert(date,<EndDate>) then 
        IIF(DATEPART(Dw,<StartDate>) in(1,7) or Convert(time,<StartDate>) >  Convert(time,<EndTime>),0 ,DateDiff(S,IIF(Convert(time,<StartDate>) < Convert(time,<StartTime>),Convert(time,<StartTime>),Convert(time,<StartDate>)), Convert(time,<EndTime>)))
        + IIF(DATEPART(Dw,<EndDate>) in(1,7) or  Convert(time,<EndDate>) <  Convert(time,<StartTime>),0,DateDiff(S,Convert(time,<StartTime>),IIF(Convert(time,<EndDate>) > Convert(time,<EndTime>), Convert(time,<EndTime>), Convert(time,<EndDate>))))
    else -333
    end --as pday

+IIF(DatePart(wEEk,<StartDate>)  = DatePart(wEEk,<EndDate>) 
,0, (DateDiff(wk,dateadd(d,-datepart(dw,<StartDate>),dateadd(ww,1,<StartDate>)),DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, <EndDate>), 6)-1) * 5)) * Datediff(S, Convert(time,<StartTime>),Convert(time,<EndTime>)) --Fullweek_days

+Case When Convert(date,<StartDate>) = Convert(date,<EndDate>) then 0
      When DatePart(wEEk,<StartDate>)  <> DatePart(wEEk,<EndDate>) then
                        IIF( datepart(dw,<StartDate>) = 7,0,DateDIFF(DAY,<StartDate>+1,dateadd(d,-datepart(dw,<StartDate>),dateadd(ww,1,<StartDate>))))  -- beginFulldays
                        +IIF( datepart(dw,<EndDate>) = 1,0,DateDIFF(DAY,DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, <EndDate>), 6),<EndDate> -1))  --Endfulldays
      When DatePart(wEEk,<StartDate>)  = DatePart(wEEk,<EndDate>) then
            DateDiff(DAY,<StartDate>+1,<EndDate> ) 
    ELSE -333 END * Datediff(S, Convert(time,<StartTime>),Convert(time,<EndTime>))
```

Here is the Function Version:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[rsf_BusinessTime]
(
@startDateTime Datetime,
@endDateTime Datetime ,
@StartTime VarChar(12),
@EndTime VarChar(12) )
RETURNS BIGINT
As
BEGIN
Declare @totalSeconds BigInt,
    @SecondsInDay int,
    @dayStart Time = Convert(time,@StartTime),
    @dayEnd Time =Convert(time,@EndTime),
    @SatAfterStart Datetime = dateadd(d,-datepart(dw,@startDateTime),dateadd(ww,1,@startDateTime)), 
    @Sunbeforend Datetime = DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, @endDateTime), 6) 

-- This function calculates the seconds between the start and end dates provided for business hours. 
-- It only returns the time between the @start and @end time (hour of day) of the work week. 
-- Weekend days are removed.
-- Holidays are not considered.  

Set @SecondsInDay = Datediff(S, @dayStart,@dayEnd) 


Set @totalSeconds = 
 --first/last/sameday
    Case when  @startDateTime= @endDateTime then 0
    When Convert(date,@startDateTime) = Convert(date,@endDateTime) Then 
         IIF( DATEPART(Dw,@startDateTime)  in(1,7)
                  or Convert(time,@startDateTime) > @dayEnd
                  or Convert(time,@endDateTime) < @dayStart,0, 
        DateDiff(S,IIF(Convert(time,@startDateTime) < @dayStart,@dayStart,Convert(time,@startDateTime))
                ,IIF(Convert(time,@endDateTime) > @dayEnd, @dayEnd, Convert(time,@endDateTime))))
    when  Convert(date,@startDateTime) <> Convert(date,@endDateTime) then 
        IIF(DATEPART(Dw,@startDateTime) in(1,7) or Convert(time,@startDateTime) >  @dayEnd,0 ,DateDiff(S,IIF(Convert(time,@startDateTime) < @dayStart,@dayStart,Convert(time,@startDateTime)), @dayEnd))
        + IIF(DATEPART(Dw,@endDateTime) in(1,7) or  Convert(time,@endDateTime) <  @dayStart,0,DateDiff(S,@dayStart,IIF(Convert(time,@endDateTime) > @dayEnd, @dayEnd, Convert(time,@endDateTime))))
    else -333
    end --as pday

+IIF(DatePart(wEEk,@startDateTime)  = DatePart(wEEk,@endDateTime)   
,0, (DateDiff(wk,@SatAfterStart,@Sunbeforend-1) * 5)) * @SecondsInDay --Fullweek_days

+Case When Convert(date,@startDateTime) = Convert(date,@endDateTime) then 0
      When DatePart(wEEk,@startDateTime)  <> DatePart(wEEk,@endDateTime) then
                        IIF( datepart(dw,@startDateTime) = 7,0,DateDIFF(DAY,@startDateTime+1,@SatAfterStart))  -- beginFulldays
                        +IIF( datepart(dw,@endDateTime) = 1,0,DateDIFF(DAY,@Sunbeforend,@endDateTime -1))  --Endfulldays
      When DatePart(wEEk,@startDateTime)  = DatePart(wEEk,@endDateTime) then
            DateDiff(DAY,@startDateTime+1,@endDateTime ) 
    ELSE -333 END * @SecondsInDay


Return @totalSeconds
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I have actually done this before, taking into account all the variables (weekends, holidays, etc) for business hours is very difficult, I think this task is best done outside SQL

Answer (score 0):

**Another way of thinking**, the below function work correctly if your first day of week is Monday otherwise you should change related lines including (6,7) to your local weekend's days

```
create function fn_worktime(@Datetime1 DateTime,@Datetime2 DateTime)
Returns BigInt
as
Begin
    Declare 
            @Date1 Date, 
            @Date2 Date,
            @DateIndex Date,
            @minutes int,
            @lastDayMinutes int,
            @StartTime int , --in minutes
            @FinishTime int ,--in minutes
            @WorkDayLong int --in minutes

    Set @StartTime  =8 * 60 + 30 -- 8:30
    Set @FinishTime =17* 60 + 30 -- 17:30
    Set @WorkDayLong =@FinishTime - @StartTime  

    Set @Date1 = Convert(Date,@DateTime1)
    Set @Date2 = Convert(Date,@DateTime2)
    Set @minutes=DateDiff(minute,@DateTime1,DateAdd(MINUTE,@FinishTime ,convert(DateTime,@Date1)))
    if @minutes<0 OR DatePart(dw,@Date1) in (6,7)  -- you can even check holdays here. '(6 Saturday,7 Sunday) according to SET DATEFIRST 1'
        Set @minutes=0

    Set @DateIndex=DateAdd(day,1,@Date1)
    While @DateIndex<@Date2
    Begin
        if DatePart(dw,@DateIndex) not in (6,7)  -- you can even check holdays here. '(6 Saturday,7 Sunday) according to SET DATEFIRST 1'
            set @minutes=@minutes+@WorkDayLong 
        Set @DateIndex=DateAdd(day,1,@DateIndex)
    End
    if DatePart(dw,@DateIndex) not in (6,7)  -- you can even check holdays here
    Begin
        set @lastDayMinutes=DateDiff(minute,DateAdd(MINUTE ,@StartTime ,convert(DateTime,@Date2)),@DateTime2)
        if @lastDayMinutes>@WorkDayLong 
            set @lastDayMinutes=@WorkDayLong 
        if @Date1<>@Date2   
            set @minutes=@minutes+@lastDayMinutes
        Else
            Set @minutes=@minutes+@lastDayMinutes-@WorkDayLong 

    End
    return @minutes
End
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this solution?

Without using loop "While".

```
create function dbo.WorkingHoursBetweenDates ( @StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime, @StartTime time, @EndTime time )
returns decimal ( 10, 2 )
as
begin

  return
    case
      when @EndTime < @StartTime or @EndDate < @StartDate then
        0
      else
        round
        ( ( dbo.WorkingDaysBetweenDates(@StartDate, @EndDate) -
            ( dbo.WorkingDaysBetweenDates(@StartDate, @StartDate) *
              case
                when cast ( @StartDate as time ) > @EndTime then
                  1
                else
                  datediff
                  ( mi,
                    @StartTime
                    , case
                        when @StartTime > cast ( @StartDate as time ) then
                          @StartTime
                        else
                          cast ( @StartDate as time )
                      end
                  ) /
                  ( datediff ( mi, @StartTime, @EndTime ) + 0.0 )
              end
            ) -
            ( dbo.WorkingDaysBetweenDates(@EndDate, @EndDate) *
              case
                when cast ( @EndDate as time ) < @StartTime then
                  1
                else
                  datediff
                  ( mi,
                    case
                      when @EndTime < cast ( @EndDate as time ) then
                        @EndTime
                      else
                        cast ( @EndDate as time )
                    end,
                    @EndTime
                  ) /
                  ( datediff ( mi, @StartTime, @EndTime ) + 0.0 )
              end
            )
          ) *
          ( datediff ( mi, @StartTime, @EndTime ) / 60.0 ), 2
        )
    end

end
------

create function dbo.WorkingDaysBetweenDates ( @StartDate date, @EndDate date )
returns int
as
begin

  return 
    ( datediff(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1 ) -
    ( datediff(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 2 ) -
    ( case when datename(dw, @StartDate) = 'Sunday' then 1 else 0 end ) -
    ( case when datename(dw, @EndDate) = 'Saturday' then 1 else 0 end ) -
    ( select
        count ( 1 )
      from
        dbo.Tb_Holidays
      where
        HDate between @StartDate and @EndDate
        and datename(dw, HDate) not in ( 'Sunday', 'Saturday' )
    )

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution, without the use of a function. Note that this relies on the existence of a [numbers table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393951/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-and-populate-a-numbers-table), populated with at least the maximum number of days the tasks you're tracking may take.

This doesn't take public holidays into account. If you don't work weekends, setting the opening and closing times to midnight in the @OpeningHours table variable should do the job.

I've tested this against 8500 rows of 'real world' data and found it to be performant.

```
DECLARE @OpeningHours TABLE ([DayOfWeek] INTEGER, OpeningTime TIME(0), ClosingTime TIME(0));

INSERT
    @OpeningHours ([DayOfWeek], OpeningTime, ClosingTime)
VALUES
    (1, '10:00', '16:00') -- Sun
    , (2, '06:30', '23:00') -- Mon
    , (3, '06:30', '23:00') -- Tue
    , (4, '06:30', '23:00') -- Wed
    , (5, '06:30', '23:00') -- Thu
    , (6, '06:30', '23:00') -- Fri
    , (7, '08:00', '20:00'); -- Sat

DECLARE @Tasks TABLE ([Description] VARCHAR(50), CreatedDateTime DATETIME, CompletedDateTime DATETIME);

INSERT
    @Tasks ([Description], CreatedDateTime, CompletedDateTime)
VALUES
    ('Make tea', '20170404 10:00', '20170404 10:12')
    , ('Make coffee', '20170404 23:35', '20170405 06:32')
    , ('Write complex SQL query', '20170406 00:00', '20170406 23:32')
    , ('Rewrite complex SQL query', '20170406 23:50', '20170410 10:50');

SELECT
    WorkingMinutesToRespond =
        SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(Tasks.CreatedDateTime AS DATE) = CAST(Tasks.CompletedDateTime AS DATE) THEN
        CASE WHEN CAST(Tasks.CreatedDateTime AS TIME) < OpeningHours.OpeningTime THEN
            -- Task created before opening time
            DATEDIFF(MINUTE, OpeningHours.OpeningTime, CAST(Tasks.CompletedDateTime AS TIME))
        ELSE
            DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Tasks.CreatedDateTime, Tasks.CompletedDateTime)
        END
    ELSE
        CASE WHEN Tasks.CoveredDate = CAST(Tasks.CreatedDateTime AS DATE) THEN 
            -- This is the day the task was created
            CASE WHEN CAST(Tasks.CreatedDateTime AS TIME(0)) > OpeningHours.ClosingTime THEN
                0 -- after working hours
            ELSE
                -- during or before working hours
                CASE WHEN CAST(Tasks.CreatedDateTime AS TIME(0)) < OpeningHours.OpeningTime THEN
                    -- before opening time; take the whole day into account
                    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, OpeningHours.OpeningTime, OpeningHours.ClosingTime)
                ELSE
                    -- during opening hours; take part of the day into account
                    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CAST(Tasks.CreatedDateTime AS TIME), OpeningHours.ClosingTime)
                END
            END
        ELSE
            -- This is the day the task was completed
            CASE WHEN Tasks.CoveredDate = CAST(Tasks.CompletedDateTime AS DATE) THEN 
                CASE WHEN CAST(Tasks.CompletedDateTime AS TIME(0)) < OpeningHours.OpeningTime THEN
                    0 -- before working hours (unlikely to occur)
                ELSE
                    -- during or after working hours
                    CASE WHEN CAST(Tasks.CompletedDateTime AS TIME(0)) > OpeningHours.ClosingTime THEN
                        -- after closing time (also unlikely); take the whole day into account
                        DATEDIFF(MINUTE, OpeningHours.OpeningTime, OpeningHours.ClosingTime)
                    ELSE
                        -- during opening hours; take part of the day into account
                        DATEDIFF(MINUTE, OpeningHours.OpeningTime, CAST(Tasks.CompletedDateTime AS TIME(0)))
                    END
                END
        ELSE
            DATEDIFF(MINUTE, OpeningHours.OpeningTime, OpeningHours.ClosingTime)
        END 
        END
    END)
    , Tasks.Description
    , Tasks.CreatedDateTime
    , Tasks.CompletedDateTime
FROM
    (
        SELECT
        Tasks.Description
        , Tasks.CreatedDateTime
        , Tasks.CompletedDateTime
        , CoveredDate = CAST(DATEADD(DAY, Numbers.Number, Tasks.CreatedDateTime) AS DATE)
    FROM
        @Tasks Tasks
        INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Numbers WHERE Number >= 0) Numbers ON DATEDIFF(DAY, Tasks.CreatedDateTime, Tasks.CompletedDateTime) >= Numbers.Number
) Tasks
INNER JOIN @OpeningHours OpeningHours ON DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Tasks.CoveredDate) = OpeningHours.[DayOfWeek]
GROUP BY
    Tasks.Description
    , Tasks.CreatedDateTime
    , Tasks.CompletedDateTime
ORDER BY
    Tasks.CompletedDateTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

A version I wrote today taking into account bank holidays. Note: This is not thoroughly tested and could no doubt be improved.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[WorkingHoursBetween2Dates]
(
    @dtFrom datetime,
    @dtTo datetime
)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tblDates AS TABLE (DateValue DATE)
    DECLARE @dFrom date = @dtFrom
    DECLARE @dTo date = @dtTo
    DECLARE @intDays int
    DECLARE @intHours int = 0
    DECLARE @dFromWorkday bit = CASE WHEN (DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @dFrom) IN ('Saturday','Sunday')) OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.BankHolidays WHERE BankHolidayDate = @dFrom) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    DECLARE @dToWorkday bit = CASE WHEN (DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @dTo) IN ('Saturday','Sunday')) OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.BankHolidays WHERE BankHolidayDate = @dTo) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END



    IF DATEPART(HOUR,@dtFrom) < 9
        SET @dtFrom = DATEADD(HOUR,9,CAST(CAST(@dtFrom AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
    ELSE
        IF DATEPART(HOUR,@dtFrom) > 17
            SET @dtFrom = DATEADD(HOUR,17,CAST(CAST(@dtFrom AS DATE) AS DATETIME))

    IF DATEPART(HOUR,@dtTo) < 9
        SET @dtTo = DATEADD(HOUR,9,CAST(CAST(@dtTo AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
    ELSE
        IF DATEPART(HOUR,@dtTo) > 17
            SET @dtTo = DATEADD(HOUR,17,CAST(CAST(@dtTo AS DATE) AS DATETIME))



    WHILE @dFrom <= @dTo
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @tblDates
        (
            DateValue
        )
            SELECT @dFrom
            WHERE NOT ((DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @dFrom) IN ('Saturday','Sunday')) OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.BankHolidays WHERE BankHolidayDate = @dFrom))
        
        SET @dFrom = DATEADD(DAY,1,@dFrom)
    END
    
    SET @intDays = CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @tblDates) THEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tblDates) - 1 ELSE 0 END

    IF @intDays = 0
        BEGIN
            IF @dFromWorkday = 1
                IF DATEPART(HOUR,@dtFrom) < 17
                    BEGIN
                        IF DATEDIFF(DAY,@dtFrom,@dtTo)=0
                            SET @intHours = DATEDIFF(HOUR,@dtFrom,@dtTo)
                        ELSE
                            SET @intHours = DATEDIFF(HOUR,@dtFrom,DATEADD(HOUR,17,CAST(CAST(@dtFrom AS DATE) AS DATETIME)))
                    END

            IF @dToWorkday = 1 AND DATEDIFF(DAY,@dtFrom,@dtTo)<>0
                IF DATEPART(HOUR,@dtTo) >= 17
                    SET @intHours = @intHours + 8
                ELSE
                    IF DATEPART(HOUR,@dtTo) > 9
                        SET @intHours = @intHours + DATEPART(HOUR,@dtTo) - 9
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            IF @dFromWorkday = 1
                IF DATEPART(HOUR,@dtFrom) < 17
                    BEGIN
                        SET @intHours = DATEDIFF(HOUR,@dtFrom,DATEADD(HOUR,17,CAST(CAST(@dtFrom AS DATE) AS DATETIME)))
                        SET @intDays = @intDays - 1
                    END

            IF DATEPART(HOUR,@dtTo) < 17
                SET @intHours = @intHours + (@intDays * 8) + CASE WHEN @dToWorkday = 1 THEN DATEDIFF(HOUR,DATEADD(HOUR,9,CAST(CAST(@dtTo AS DATE) AS DATETIME)), @dtTo) ELSE 0 END
            ELSE
                SET @intHours = @intHours + ((@intDays + 1) * 8)
        END

    RETURN (@intHours)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just hit this issue and come up with the following solution.  It takes as start and end time for the working day, works out the minutes used for partial days, removes lunch breaks if more than x hours have been worked, and removes weekends and bank holidays.

Here's the working out:
Date From "2020-09-09 07:49" to "2020-12-18 08:27:00.000" = 34598 minutes

> ```
> = 101 days
>   - 28 weekends
>   = 73 days (71 minus start and end partial days)
>   = 34080 minutes (568 hours x 71 whole days @ 8 hours per day) 
>       + start date 07:49 to 17:00 with an hour for lunch (8 hours 11 minutes) = 491 (551 minutes - 60 for lunch)
>       + end date 08:00 to 08:27 = 27 minutes
>   = 34080 + 491 + 27 = 34598
> ```

```
CREATE TABLE bankHoliday (
    bhDate DATE
) ON [PRIMARY]

-- 2021
INSERT INTO bankHoliday (bhDate) VALUES ('2021-01-01' );
INSERT INTO bankHoliday (bhDate) VALUES ('2021-04-02' );
INSERT INTO bankHoliday (bhDate) VALUES ('2021-04-05' );
INSERT INTO bankHoliday (bhDate) VALUES ('2021-05-03' );
INSERT INTO bankHoliday (bhDate) VALUES ('2021-05-31' );
INSERT INTO bankHoliday (bhDate) VALUES ('2021-08-30' );
INSERT INTO bankHoliday (bhDate) VALUES ('2021-12-27' );
INSERT INTO bankHoliday (bhDate) VALUES ('2021-12-28' );

DROP FUNCTION dbo.[fn_GetTotalWorkingMinutes];
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [fn_GetTotalWorkingMinutes]
(
    @DateFrom Datetime,
    @DateTo Datetime
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @StartOfDay TIME = '08:00:00'
    DECLARE @EndOfDay TIME = '17:00:00'
    DECLARE @Lunch INT = 60
    DECLARE @ThresholdForLunch INT = 300    -- 5 hours x 60 mins, assume x minutes for lunch (working 8:00AM to after 1:00PM, or before 12:00PM to 5:00pm will probably include lunch)
    DECLARE @WorkingMinutes INT = 0

    ;WITH seq(n) AS 
    (
        -- Get an integer sequence number starting from zero, per day between From and To dates
        SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT n + 1 FROM seq
        WHERE n < DATEDIFF(DAY, @DateFrom, @DateTo)
    ),
    d(Id,calDate,dayNum) AS
    (
        -- Return the sequence as an Id, the dates between From and To, and the Day-of-week number (1 = Sunday, 7 = Saturday)
        SELECT      n AS Id
        ,           DATEADD(DAY, n, @DateFrom) AS calDate
        ,           DATEPART(dw, DATEADD( DAY, n, @DateFrom)) AS dayNum
        FROM        seq
    ),
    src AS
    (
        SELECT      Id
        ,           CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), d.calDate, 126) AS date) AS calDate
        ,           dayNum
        ,           CASE
                        WHEN FORMAT(d.calDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd' ) = FORMAT(@DateFrom, 'yyyy-MM-dd' ) THEN @DateFrom         -- Return the Date From with Start Time
                        ELSE CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), d.calDate, 126) AS datetime) + CAST(@StartOfDay AS datetime)    -- Add the Start of Day Time to each day
                    END AS calStartDateTime
        ,           CASE
                        WHEN FORMAT(d.calDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd' ) = FORMAT(@DateTo, 'yyyy-MM-dd' ) THEN @DateTo             -- Return the Date To with End Time
                        ELSE CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), d.calDate, 126) AS datetime) + CAST(@EndOfDay AS datetime)      -- Add the End of Day Time to each day
                    END AS calEndDateTime
        FROM        d
        -- Exclude Bank Holidays
        LEFT JOIN   dbo.bankHoliday bh
        ON          bh.bhDate = d.caldate
        WHERE       bh.bhDate IS NULL   -- Exclude Bank Holidays
                    AND d.dayNum > 1    -- After Sunday
                    AND d.dayNum < 7    -- Before Saturday
    )
    /* For Debugging
    SELECT      Id
    ,           calDate
    ,           calStartDateTime
    ,           calEndDateTime
    ,           CASE 
                    WHEN DATEDIFF(minute, calStartDateTime, calEndDateTime) > 5 THEN DATEDIFF(minute, calStartDateTime, calEndDateTime) - @Lunch        -- Take an hour off for lunch if more than 5 hours have been worked 
                    ELSE DATEDIFF(minute, calStartDateTime, calEndDateTime) 
                END AS WorkingHours
    */

    SELECT      @WorkingMinutes = SUM(
                    CASE 
                        WHEN DATEDIFF(minute, calStartDateTime, calEndDateTime) > @ThresholdForLunch THEN DATEDIFF(minute, calStartDateTime, calEndDateTime) - @Lunch   -- Take an hour off for lunch if more than 5 hours have been worked 
                        ELSE DATEDIFF(minute, calStartDateTime, calEndDateTime) 
                    END 
                ) 

    FROM        src
    --ORDER BY  calDate
    OPTION      (MAXRECURSION 0);
  
RETURN (@workingMinutes);

END

GO

SELECT  requested
,       solved
,       dbo.[fn_GetTotalWorkingMinutes](requested, solved)
FROM    MyTable
```