# Salesforce calculate busisness time between dates

Tags: datetime, salesforce

I tried to use [Salesforce formula: Calculate business hours between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126378/salesforce-formula-calculate-business-hours-between-two-dates) to count business hours between dates/times. However, for some records it returns negatives or 0 even though there is > 45 mins between the date/Times.

Any reason why this would be happening.

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide some more info ? What exactly your formula looks like ? Which dates give wrong results ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
I ended up building a different method of calculation that works perfect.

The logic in the formula linked to above was slightly flawed.

Comment: We have the same same scenario can I know how you overcomed this