# SQL Business Hours Calculation Error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime, business-intelligence

Hoping someone can tell me where I am going wrong here, I started with a Business Hours query found at [Calculate business hours between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274208/calculate-business-hours-between-two-dates), it's the second top answer because the top answer was not providing the correct output upon testing.  The issue I am having is when I cross over to a new day and the end datetime exceeds the Business Day End.  Here is my test:

select dbo.BusinessSeconds('09:00:00','17:00:00','2014-12-24 16:59:59','2014-12-26 18:00:00');

So if I go from 1 second before COB to the start of the next day, I get 1 second, which is correct. If I go from the same start to the end of the day the next day, I get 28801, or 1 full day and 1 second - which is also correct.  However, if I extend the date end time to 17:00:01 through 17:59:59 it also includes those seconds but if I hit 18:00:00, the time truncates back to the original 17:00:00 end of day.  So I will get correct data for any given end time unless it is during the 17:00:00-17:59:59 timeframes and then I potentially get up to an extra hour of time that I should not have.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have a deliverable on this by tomorrow.

```
ALTER Function [dbo].[BusinessSeconds](@BusinessDayStart TIME,@BusinessDayEnd TIME,@StartDate DATETIME,@EndDate DATETIME) Returns Int
AS
Begin
--TEST: select dbo.BusinessSeconds('09:00:00','17:00:00','2014-12-24 16:59:59','2014-12-26 18:00:00');
Declare @WorkMin INT = 0   -- Initialize counter
Declare @Reverse BIT       -- Flag to hold if direction is reverse
Declare @StartHour TIME = @BusinessDayStart   -- Start of business hours (can be supplied as an argument if needed)
Declare @EndHour TIME = @BusinessDayEnd    -- End of business hours (can be supplied as an argument if needed)
Declare @Holidays Table (HDate DateTime)   --  Table variable to hold holidayes

-- If dates are in reverse order, switch them and set flag
If @StartDate>@EndDate 
Begin
    Declare @TempDate DateTime=@StartDate
    Set @StartDate=@EndDate
    Set @EndDate=@TempDate
    Set @Reverse=1
End
Else Set @Reverse = 0

-- Get country holidays from table based on the country code (Feel free to remove this or modify as per your DB schema)
-- Insert Into @Holidays(HDate) select DATEADD(month,((LEFT(CAL_ID,4)-1900)*12)+LEFT(RIGHT(CAL_ID,4),2)-1,RIGHT(CAL_ID,2)-1) from B_CALENDAR where CAL_DAY_PK = 263 and HDATE >= DateAdd(dd, DateDiff(dd,0,@StartDate), 0)
Insert Into @Holidays (HDate) Select HolidayDate from V_BUS_HOL Where HolidayDate >= DateAdd(dd, DateDiff(dd,0,@StartDate), 0)

If CAST(@StartDate as TIME) < @StartHour Set @StartDate = CAST(CAST(@StartDate as DATE) as DATETIME) + CAST(@StartHour as DATETIME)  -- If Start time is less than start hour, set it to start hour
If CAST(@StartDate as TIME) >= DATEADD(HOUR,1,@EndHour) Set @StartDate = CAST(CAST(DATEADD(DAY,1,@StartDate) as DATE) as DATETIME) + CAST(@StartHour as DATETIME) -- If Start time is after end hour, set it to start hour of next day
If CAST(@EndDate as TIME) >= DATEADD(HOUR,1,@EndHour) Set @EndDate = CAST(CAST(@EndDate as DATE) as DATETIME) + CAST(@EndHour as DATETIME)  -- If End time is after end hour, set it to end hour
If CAST(@EndDate as TIME) < @StartHour Set @EndDate = CAST(CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-1,@EndDate) as DATE) as DATETIME) + CAST(@EndHour as DATETIME) -- If End time is before start hour, set it to end hour of previous day

If @StartDate>@EndDate Return 0

-- If Start and End is on same day
If DateDiff(Day,@StartDate,@EndDate) <= 0
Begin
    If Datepart(dw,@StartDate)>1 And DATEPART(dw,@StartDate)<7  -- If day is between sunday and saturday
        If (Select Count(*) From @Holidays Where HDATE=DateAdd(dd, DateDiff(dd,0,@StartDate), 0)) = 0  -- If day is not a holiday
            If @EndDate<@StartDate Return 0 Else Set @WorkMin=DATEDIFF(SECOND, @StartDate, @EndDate) -- Calculate difference
        Else Return 0
    Else Return 0
End
Else Begin
    Declare @Partial int=1   -- Set partial day flag
    While DateDiff(Day,@StartDate,@EndDate) > 0   -- While start and end days are different
    Begin
        If Datepart(dw,@StartDate)>1 And DATEPART(dw,@StartDate)<7    --  If this is a weekday
        Begin
            If (Select Count(*) From @Holidays Where HDATE=DateAdd(dd, DateDiff(dd,0,@StartDate), 0)) = 0  -- If this is not a holiday
            Begin
                If @Partial=1  -- If this is the first iteration, calculate partial time
                Begin 
                    Set @WorkMin=@WorkMin + DATEDIFF(SECOND, @StartDate, DateAdd(hour, DATEPART(HOUR,@EndHour), DateDiff(DAY, 0, @StartDate)))
                    Set @StartDate=DateAdd(hour, DATEPART(HOUR,@StartHour)+24, DateDiff(DAY, 0, @StartDate))
                    Set @Partial=0 
                End
                Else Begin      -- If this is a full day, add full minutes
                    Set @WorkMin=@WorkMin + (DATEPART(HOUR,@EndHour)-DATEPART(HOUR,@StartHour))*60        
                    Set @StartDate = DATEADD(DD,1,@StartDate)
                End
            End
            Else Set @StartDate = DATEADD(DD,1,@StartDate)  
        End
        Else Set @StartDate = DATEADD(DD,1,@StartDate)
    End
    If Datepart(dw,@StartDate)>1 And DATEPART(dw,@StartDate)<7  -- If last day is a weekday
        If (Select Count(*) From @Holidays Where HDATE=DateAdd(dd, DateDiff(dd,0,@StartDate), 0)) = 0   -- And it is not a holiday
            If @Partial=0 Set @WorkMin=@WorkMin + DATEDIFF(SECOND, @StartDate, @EndDate) Else Set @WorkMin=@WorkMin + DATEDIFF(SECOND, DateAdd(hour, DATEPART(HOUR,@StartHour), DateDiff(DAY, 0, @StartDate)), @EndDate)
End 
If @Reverse=1 Set @WorkMin=-@WorkMin
Return @WorkMin
End
```

Comment: So how do you want to handle times that start before `@BusinessDayStart` and/or end after `@BusinessDayEnd`? Just truncate/ignore the time that exists outside of those boundaries? That's what it sounds like.

Comment: Jan 8: "I have a business deliverable on this tomorrow". Then silence.

Comment: Apologies Ross, I figured out a fix to the formula but at this point, I don't remember what the solution actually was and I no longer have access to the query as it was at my former job.

Answer (score 0):

This one is an old one, however I believe that your problem is datetime/time data types.  You didn't state the version of SQL Server you are using but if you have 2008 or above, you may want to adjust your tables and this function to use the datetime2 format.  It is more accurate.  datetime/smalldatetime both are only accurate to a certain point, then they round which could cause the problem you are looking at.