# Calculate no. of working hours between two given dates(exclude the weekends)

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I want to calculate no. of working hours between two given dates(excluding weekends) and it should be within business hours(8:00 AM - 5:00 PM).

I have 3 tables:

- table 1 contains open dates and closed dates for different jobs.
- table 2 contains the working hours(2 columns start time(8:00 AM) and end time(5:00 PM)).
- Table 3 contains date and the day on that date.

For eg.

> open date     - 2015-10-16 06:00:00  &  closed date - 2015-10-19
>   15:00:00 working_hours_start - 8:00 AM  & working_hours_end  - 5:00 PM
>
> Answer - 16 hrs

Answer (score 4):

I had this requirement and have written complete function that can calculate while avoiding hours of weekend and holidays for a given country (using a separate table). I have put the whole function and details on my blog (http://mgw.dumatics.com/mysql-function-to-calculate-elapsed-working-time/) along with explanation and flowchart and creation of holiday table etc...

Example of problem resolved:

Let's say an incident was logged on "Friday 10th June 2016 at 12:00" for a site in the "UK" which opens between 09:00 to 16:00. This incident was then closed on "Tuesday 14th June 2016 at 14:00".

For the above incident function should calculate the age as 960 minutes = 16 hours = [4 hours on Friday (12:00 to 16:00) + 7 hours on Monday (09:00 to 16:00) + 5 hours on Tuesday (09:00 to 14:00)]

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE FUNCTION WorkTime 
(
    reported_datetime DATETIME,
    closed_datetime   DATETIME
)
RETURNS DOUBLE

BEGIN

    DECLARE FirstDay, LastDay, CurrentDate, LastDate DATE;
    DECLARE StartTime, FinishTime, WorkStart, WorkFinish, DailyWorkTime TIME;

    DECLARE Temp DOUBLE;
    SET     Temp = 0;

    SET FirstDay   = DATE(reported_datetime);
    SET LastDay    = DATE(closed_datetime);
    SET StartTime  = TIME(reported_datetime);
    SET FinishTime = TIME(closed_datetime);
    SET WorkStart  = '08:00:00';
    SET WorkFinish = '17:00:00';
    SET DailyWorkTime = TIMEDIFF(WorkFinish,WorkStart);

    IF (StartTime < WorkStart)
    THEN
        SET StartTime = WorkStart;
    END IF;
    IF (FinishTime > WorkFinish)
    THEN
        SET FinishTime = WorkFinish;
    END IF;

    SET CurrentDate    = FirstDay;
    SET LastDate       = LastDay;
    WHILE(CurrentDate <= LastDate)
    DO       
        IF (DAYOFWEEK(CurrentDate)!=1 AND DAYOFWEEK(CurrentDate)!=7)
        THEN
            IF (CurrentDate != FirstDay) AND (CurrentDate != LastDay)
            THEN
                SET Temp = Temp + TIME_TO_SEC(DailyWorkTime)/3600;

            ELSEIF (CurrentDate = FirstDay) AND (CurrentDate != LastDay) 
            THEN
                SET Temp = Temp + GREATEST(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(WorkFinish,StartTime)),0)/3600;

            ELSEIF (CurrentDate != FirstDay) AND (CurrentDate = LastDay)
            THEN
                SET Temp = Temp + GREATEST(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(FinishTime,WorkStart)),0)/3600;

            ELSEIF (CurrentDate = FirstDay) AND (CurrentDate = LastDay)
            THEN
                SET Temp = TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(FinishTime,StartTime))/3600;

            END IF;
        END IF;

        SET CurrentDate = DATE_ADD(CurrentDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    END WHILE;

    IF Temp < 0
    THEN
        SET Temp = 0; 
    END IF;
    RETURN Temp;
END$$;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try mysql **timediff**

```
time_to_sec(timediff('2015-10-16 06:00:00', '2015-10-19 15:00:00 ' )) / 3600
```

Day not saturday and sunday

```
where WEEKDAY(date) !=5 and WEEKDAY(date) !=6
```

and try query like this demo

```
select *,time_to_sec(timediff(date_note1, date_note2)) / 3600 from (SELECT CASE
    WHEN DATE_FORMAT(date,'%H:%i:%s')  < '8:00:00' THEN CONCAT(date, ' 8:00:00')
    ELSE date
    END AS date_note1 ,

    CASE
    WHEN DATE_FORMAT(date2,'%H:%i:%s')  > '17:00:00' THEN CONCAT(date2, ' 17:00:00')
    ELSE date2
    END AS date_note2

    FROM `test` where WEEKDAY(date) !=5 and WEEKDAY(date) !=6) as tbl
```

Comment: Yes, but it will show the total time between these two dates which will include saturday and sunday and it will also include the time other than business hours, which i want to exclude.

Comment: The given query will convert the start_datetime to 8:00:00 if it is less then 8:00:00 else it will remain same, and same for end_datetime and will calculate the total hours suppose from 8:00 of 16oct to 15:00 of 18oct which will include extra hours. What I want is that for 16 oct it should calculate from 8:00 - 17:00, same for 17 oct and 8:00 to 15:00 for 18 oct.

Comment: Also here "where WEEKDAY(date) !=5 and WEEKDAY(date) !=6" which  date should I include, it will accept either the start date or end date and will check for that particular date....but it should also check for the days for dates in between those given dates.

Comment: I am new to queries ....so please help.
Here is the similar question but in sql, can you convert it to mysql.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274208/calculate-business-hours-between-two-dates