# Need dates difference in hh:mm:ss

Tags: sql

I have two columns in my table named as "start date" and "end date".
I need difference of two tables and result as "completion time" in hh:mm:ss.
Please help

Comment: Please visit here and updated your question : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What DBMS?  Update issue and tag with appropriate DBMS, as solution depends on DBMS type and what column types you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of several questions. Listed a couple below,

[SQL time difference between two dates result in hh:mm:ss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577898/sql-time-difference-between-two-dates-result-in-hhmmss)

[Calculate business hours between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274208/calculate-business-hours-between-two-dates)