# Issue while calculating SLA in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

### I am using below function to calculate the elapsed time between 2 input timestamps. Only time spent during business hours should be calculated. Business hrs are Mon-Sat 8 am to 6 pm.

Function call syntax:
select xxxxx('2018.09.28 19:02:28','2018-09-29 10:40:35') Function is giving output as 98 mins, the correct answer is 160 mins.

---

Function structure is:

```
Create FUNCTION xxxxx (@LeadAssignTime DATETIME, @LeadContactTime DATETIME)
RETURNS VARCHAR(9)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Temp BIGINT
    SET @Temp=0

    DECLARE @LeadAssignDay VARCHAR(9)
    SET @LeadAssignDay = CONVERT(VARCHAR(9),@LeadAssignTime, 112)

    DECLARE @LeadContactDay VARCHAR(9)
    SET @LeadContactDay = CONVERT(VARCHAR(9),@LeadContactTime, 112)

    DECLARE @StartTime VARCHAR(9)
    SET @StartTime = CONVERT(VARCHAR(9),@LeadAssignTime, 108)

    DECLARE @FinishTime VARCHAR(9)
    SET @FinishTime = CONVERT(VARCHAR(9),@LeadContactTime, 108)

    DECLARE @WorkStart VARCHAR(9)
    SET @WorkStart = '08:00:00'

    DECLARE @WorkFinish VARCHAR(9)
    SET @WorkFinish = '18:00:00'

    IF (@StartTime<@WorkStart)
    BEGIN
        SET @StartTime = @WorkStart
    END
    IF (@FinishTime>@WorkFinish)
    BEGIN
        SET @FinishTime=@WorkFinish
    END

DECLARE @CurrentDate VARCHAR(9)
    SET @CurrentDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(9),@LeadAssignTime, 112)
    DECLARE @LastDate VARCHAR(9)
    SET @LastDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(9),@LeadContactTime, 112)

WHILE(@CurrentDate<=@LastDate)
BEGIN       

        IF (DATEPART(dw, @CurrentDate)!=1 )
        BEGIN
              IF (@CurrentDate!=@LeadAssignDay) AND (@CurrentDate!=@LeadContactDay)
              BEGIN
                   SET @Temp = (@Temp + (8*60))

              END

              ELSE IF (@CurrentDate=@LeadAssignDay) AND (@CurrentDate!=@LeadContactDay)
              BEGIN
                SET @Temp = @Temp + DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartTime, @WorkFinish)

              END

              ELSE IF (@CurrentDate!=@LeadAssignDay) AND (@CurrentDate=@LeadContactDay)
              BEGIN
                SET @Temp = @Temp + DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @WorkStart, @FinishTime)

              END

              ELSE IF (@CurrentDate=@LeadAssignDay) AND (@CurrentDate=@LeadContactDay)
              BEGIN
                SET @Temp = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartTime, @FinishTime)

              END

             END

SET @CurrentDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(9),DATEADD(day, 1, @CurrentDate),112)

END
        Return @TEMP

END
```

Comment: This is the same as work time between two dates which has been asked and answered. Your code looks similar but does not match. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274208/calculate-business-hours-between-two-dates

Comment: I would caution you against using scalar functions like this. They are horribly inefficient and slow. Then adding a cursor inside it is a performance timebomb. What you really need is a calendar table. It allows to do this kind of thing set based and offers the flexibility of things like holidays, the random required Saturday or even partial days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going around your loop twice, but in the first iteration, you fall into the second IF block and setting @temp to be -62

In the second iteration, you fall into the third IF block and calculate 160 for the difference between @WorkStart and @FinishTime, but then this is added to the value already in @Temp.   160-62 = 98.

You'll need your second IF block to check if 'start time' is before 'work finish' before executing that logic.

```
(@CurrentDate=@LeadAssignDay) AND (@CurrentDate!=@LeadContactDay)
```

needs to become

```
(@CurrentDate=@LeadAssignDay) AND (@CurrentDate!=@LeadContactDay) AND ( @StartTime < @WorkFinish)
```

I haven't done any vetting beyond the one use case.  Make sure to do some thorough testing.

Comment: I will do more testing on this.