# Select Range of Dates, Including Ones With No Results

Tags: sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server: How to select all days in a date range even if no data exists for some days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899829/sql-server-how-to-select-all-days-in-a-date-range-even-if-no-data-exists-for-so)

I wasn't really sure how to word this question, but I'll try to explain. I'm trying to build some basic reporting using queries like the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, h_date FROM (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), h_time, 102) AS h_date FROM hits h GROUP BY h_date ORDER BY h_date
```

This returns results like this, which I use to build a graph:

```
8 2012.05.06
2 2012.05.07
9 2012.05.09
```

As you can see, it's missing the 8th as there were no hits on that day. Is there a way to get a value of `0` for dates that have no results, or will I have to parse the results after the fact and add them manually?

Comment: Hey Norla, thanks for the link. I guess I just hadn't worded it right when I searched. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use existing catalog views to derive a sequential range of dates between your start date and your end date. Then you can just left join to your data, and any missing dates will be there with 0s.

```
DECLARE @min SMALLDATETIME, @max SMALLDATETIME;

SELECT @min = MIN(h_time), @max = MAX(h_time)
  FROM dbo.hits 
  -- WHERE ?

-- or if you just want a fixed range:

-- SELECT @min = '20120101', @max = '20120131';

;WITH n(d) AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @min, @max)+1) 
   DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) - 1, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @min))
  FROM sys.all_objects ORDER BY [object_id]
)
SELECT n.d, [count] = COUNT(h.h_time)
  FROM n
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.hits AS h
  ON h.h_time >= n.d
  AND h.h_time < DATEADD(DAY, 1, n.d)
  -- AND --WHERE clause against hits?
  GROUP BY n.d;
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! You even wrote in where column and table names would go, which is a big help to me. I hope to, one day, be an SQL wizard like you. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've never been a big fan of using system tables to create dummy records to join against, but it's a very common approach.

I took Aaron Bertrand's answer and changed the Common Table Expression (CTE) to use a recursive one instead. It's quicker as it doesn't have to hit a table to do the query. Not that the previous version is slow anyway.

You need to specify "OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);" otherwise it will limit the number of rows returned to the default (100).  The value of 0 will return unlimited rows.

```
DECLARE @min SMALLDATETIME, @max SMALLDATETIME;

--SELECT @min = MIN(h_time), @max = MAX(h_time)
--  FROM dbo.hits 

SELECT @min = '20120101', @max = '20121231';


WITH recursedate(each_date, date_index) AS
(
SELECT @min, 0 

UNION ALL 
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,date_index+1,@min), date_index+1
    FROM recursedate
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY,date_index+1,@min) <= @max
)



SELECT recursedate.each_date, [count] = COUNT(h.h_time)
  FROM recursedate
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.hits AS h
  ON --CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME,h.h_time) =  recursedate.dates 
  h.h_time >= recursedate.each_date
   AND h.h_time < DATEADD(DAY, 1, recursedate.each_date)
  -- AND --WHERE clause against hits?
  GROUP BY recursedate.each_date
   OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0); -- The default is 100 so you'll only get 100 dates, 0 is unlimited.
```