# How does one summarise data grouped by a column and date, accounting for dates with missing data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm creating a report where I'd like to get the number of events grouped by day and tag, filtered by specific tags (like '%sample%') and for a specific period (e.g. past week).

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

There are days however when no events with a specific tag occurred. The problem I have is how to generate rows for days for which no rows exist and give them a value of zero.  Something similar to the following:

```
Tag                 Date            Count
=================== =============== ====================
Sample              2013-07-07      0
Sample              2013-07-08      0
Sample              2013-07-09      0
Sample              2013-07-10      0
Sample              2013-07-11      0
Sample              2013-07-12      1
Sample              2013-07-13      0
xxx Sample xxx      2013-07-07      0
xxx Sample xxx      2013-07-08      0
xxx Sample xxx      2013-07-09      0
xxx Sample xxx      2013-07-10      3
xxx Sample xxx      2013-07-11      0
xxx Sample xxx      2013-07-12      0
xxx Sample xxx      2013-07-13      0
yyy Sample yyy      2013-07-07      0
yyy Sample yyy      2013-07-08      0
yyy Sample yyy      2013-07-09      0
yyy Sample yyy      2013-07-10      1
yyy Sample yyy      2013-07-11      0
yyy Sample yyy      2013-07-12      0
yyy Sample yyy      2013-07-13      0
```

The zero days are important in order to render the data in graphs, where each "tag" is its own graph, where the time is the X-axis or count is the Y-axis.

### **Schema**

The Tags table look as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Tags
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Tags] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    (
          [Id] ASC
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And Events table look as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Events](
      [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
      [Message] [varchar](128) NULL,
      [TagId] [int] NOT NULL,
      [CreatedAt] [datetime] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Events] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    (
      [Id] ASC
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
)
```

Where TagId is a foreign key to the Tags table.

### **Sample Data**

The Events table has the following data

```
Id  Message     TagId   CreatedAt
=== =========== ======= =========================
1   Message 1   1       2013-07-10 18:46:04.967
2   Message 2   2       2013-07-14 18:46:10.547
3   Message 3   3       2013-07-12 18:46:15.190
4   Message 4   4       2013-07-14 18:46:20.673
5   Message 5   2       2013-07-14 18:46:28.133
8   Message 6   1       2013-07-10 14:46:04.967
9   Message 7   1       2013-07-10 12:46:04.967
10  Message 6   2       2013-07-10 14:46:04.967
```

And the tags table has the following data:

```
Id  Name
=== ===========================
3   Sample
4   Test1
5   Test2
6   Test3
1   xxx Sample xxx
2   yyy Sample yyy
```

### **What I've tried**

So, I joined it with a table getting the following:

```
SELECT Tags.Name, CONVERT(date, Events.CreatedAt) AS Date,COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM
Events
INNER JOIN Tags ON Events.TagId = Tags.Id
where tags.Name like '%sample%'
GROUP BY Tags.Name, CONVERT(date, Events.CreatedAt)
ORDER BY Tags.Name, CONVERT(date, Events.CreatedAt)
```

which returned

```
Name                Date            Count
=================== =============== ================
Sample              2013-07-12      1
xxx Sample xxx      2013-07-10      3
yyy Sample yyy      2013-07-10      1
yyy Sample yyy      2013-07-14      2
```

I searched for ways to generated rows for days for which there is no data. I found an entry 
[SQL Server: How to select all days in a date range even if no data exists for some days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899829/sql-server-how-to-select-all-days-in-a-date-range-even-if-no-data-exists-for-so) but was unable to get it to work.

To verify I got the right days, I ran the following query:

```
WITH DateTable
AS
(
    SELECT CONVERT(date, DateAdd(WEEK, -1, GETDATE())) AS [DATE]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, [DATE])
    FROM DateTable
    WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, [DATE]) < CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
)
select DateTable.DATE
FROM DateTable
```

Which returned:

```
2013-07-07
2013-07-08
2013-07-09
2013-07-10
2013-07-11
2013-07-12
2013-07-13
```

My first attempt was to get it to work without specifying the `LIKE '%sample%'` in the where clause.

```
WITH DateTable
AS
(
    SELECT CONVERT(date, DateAdd(WEEK, -1, GETDATE())) AS [DATE]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, [DATE])
    FROM DateTable
    WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, [DATE]) < CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
)
SELECT Tags.Name, dt.[DATE] as Date, COUNT(Events.ID) as Count
FROM
      Events
      INNER JOIN Tags ON Tags.Id = Events.TagId
RIGHT JOIN [DateTable] dt ON dt.[DATE] = CONVERT(date, Events.[CreatedAt])
WHERE TagId IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Tags.Name, dt.[DATE]
```

I get the following result:

```
Name                Date            Count
=================== =============== ================
xxx Sample xxx      2013-07-10      3
yyy Sample yyy      2013-07-10      1
Sample              2013-07-12      1
```

I have tried other things, like changing the `RIGHT JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN`, but I'm unable to get the desired result.

Comment: I would say the problem with the last attempt is the inner join between Events and Tags.  Your right join will return a null event record with a date from [DataTable], but then an inner join to Tags will exclude all records.  If you did a right join there you would see all dates, but not all dates for all tags....

Comment: Yes. Then I had a number of `NULL` Tag Names for the dates where the event didn't occur.

Comment: You could use a Cartesian join between events and tags, although not something I would generally recommend, it does seem to fit your requirements.  So something like `from Events, Tags right join DateTable ... where Tags.Id = Events.TagId or Events.TagId = null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH DateTable
AS
(
    SELECT CONVERT(date, DateAdd(WEEK, -1, GETDATE())) AS [DATE]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, [DATE])
    FROM DateTable
    WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, [DATE]) < CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
)
SELECT Tags.Name, dt.DATE as Date,COUNT(Events.ID) as Count
FROM DateTable dt
CROSS JOIN Tags Tags
LEFT JOIN Events ON dt.[DATE] = CONVERT(date, Events.[CreatedAt])
and Tags.Id = Events.TagId
where tags.Name like '%sample%'
GROUP BY Tags.Name, Date
ORDER BY Tags.Name, Date;
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e6ffb/27)

Comment: Perfect. Would you mind to explain how you got to this answer? Such information will be invaluable to other folks reading the question and then the answer.

Comment: The first idea is to make a result set of all the tags and dates. as here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e6ffb/22 .... So applied a cross join. Then left join events table to get the count.

Comment: @Praveen: don't execute such rCTE on large result sets (say, 50 years)  or you'll get poor performance. There surely are faster solutions for tally tables.

Comment: Yup.. I didnt know about tally tables. Thanks for the tip

Comment: How would a tally table make it better?