# Display number zero, when it has no data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm doing a search on some tables, I want to calculate the result of a table, and when it does not have data on the date I set, I want to show the number zero.

```
SELECT 
    l.key as "Licença",
    coalesce(sum(c."customersAmount"), 0) as "Comsumo dos ultimos 30 dias"
FROM
    consumptions c
LEFT JOIN licenses l on c."licenseKey"=l.key
WHERE 
    c."consumedAt" >= current_date - interval '30' day AND
    l.label LIKE '%Casa%'
GROUP BY 
    l.key
ORDER BY 
    l.key ASC;
```

The lkey that has no consumption, I want to display the number zero (0).

how can I do this ?
thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server: How to select all days in a date range even if no data exists for some days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899829/sql-server-how-to-select-all-days-in-a-date-range-even-if-no-data-exists-for-so)

Comment: I can not apply this solution.

Comment: Or this. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72419/filling-in-missing-dates-in-record-set-from-generate-series. The point is, you need to generate a list of dates to account for the ones that aren't in your data. This question has been asked and answered for every flavor of sql many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want the `licenses` table as the first table in the `LEFT JOIN`, so I think this is the query you want:

```
SELECT l.key as "Licença",
       coalesce(sum(c."customersAmount"), 0) as "Comsumo dos ultimos 30 dias"
FROM licenses l LEFT JOIN
     consumptions c
     ON c."licenseKey" = l.key AND
        c."consumedAt" >= current_date - interval '30' day
WHERE l.label LIKE '%Casa%'
GROUP BY l.key
ORDER BY l.key ASC;
```

Comment: I think that's exactly what you said, I'll try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
CASE WHEN l.key NULL THEN 'Empty' ELSE l.key END as "Licença"
```

or

```
coalesce(l.key, 'Empty') AS "Licença"
```

Comment: If a given date doesn't appear in the data, it doesn't through a `NULL` to `COALESCE` against. There just isn't a record there at all, and this won't help with that.

Answer (score 0):

You should move `c."consumedAt" >= current_date - interval '30' day` from the `WHERE` to the `ON` clause. In the `WHERE` it filters all row out, where no row from `licenses` were joined as `"consumedAt"` is null for them which is never larger than or equal to any other value.

```
SELECT l.key "Licença",
       coalesce(sum(c."customersAmount"), 0) "Comsumo dos ultimos 30 dias"
       FROM consumptions c
            LEFT JOIN licenses l
                      ON c."licenseKey" = l.key
                         AND c."consumedAt" >= current_date - interval '30' day
       WHERE l.label LIKE '%Casa%'
       GROUP BY l.key
       ORDER BY l.key ASC;
```