# passing multiple parameters in SSRS?

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

I have this report parameter, named @LeadSource2.
[image]

Will it work when I pass it to my final SP that will use in (@LeadSource2) in the code…?

[image]

I don’t understand if Stored Procedures do not accept multiple values for a parameter, why SSRS has the option to pass multiple values?!

I have it like this on my report:
[image]

And in my SP I do 'where LS in (@LeadSource2).'

Its not showing me results, so I think it does not work…

My question is why SSRS would allow me to do that if the SP wouldn’t accept it?

Comment: Have you tried it?  How is your sproc set up to receive multiple parameters?  Are you expecting one output, many `union`ed together, multiple reports?

Comment: SSRS doesn't know you're using a sproc, and you can pass multiple values to SQL and to a Data Model. So it makes sense for that functionality to be there even though the sproc won't accept it. In any case; your question seems to be answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764010/how-to-pass-multiple-values-to-single-parameter-in-stored-procedure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass multiple values to single parameter in stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764010/how-to-pass-multiple-values-to-single-parameter-in-stored-procedure)

Comment: So, basically there is no way I can do inside an SP:  in (@parameter). This is forcing me to copy the SPs code to the ‘text’ seccion of the dataset in the SSRS, which doesn’t seem to be like a best practice…

Answer (score 0):

If you were using the `in(@LeadSource2)` syntax in a direct SQL dataset, it would work fine.  Whereas because you are using a sproc, as Dan says, you will need to be more involved.

Use the `join` expression in your Parameter Values properties window to pass your multi-select values to your sproc as a comma/pipe/whatever separated list and then use a string splitting function to parse it out into multiple values you can use in your sproc.