# How to pass List of arrays into SQL Server 2008 stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

From C# code I need to pass list of arrays to stored procedure.
Each array is a triple like (param1, param2, param3). So list will look like :

{(param1, param2, param3), (param1, param2, param3), (param1, param2, param3)... }

In the stored procedure I want to Insert each triple (param1, param2, param3) to table as seperate row.

Please advise how it's possible to implement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: would  you pls take a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097079/c-sharp-sql-server-passing-a-list-to-a-stored-procedure?rq=1

Comment: you could also look at "How to pass an array into a SQL Server stored procedure":
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102358/how-to-pass-an-array-into-a-sql-server-stored-procedure

Comment: Probably you may want to simplify a procedure to take only 3 parameters, and invoke it in a loop in the same transaction?