# store json data in database using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, json.net

```
temp= {
       "Vikas": 1,
       "Pravin": 2,
       "Akshay": 5,
       "Vijay": 3,
       "Prasad": 4 
      }
```

This is value I am getting in temp variable I want to store this data in database with one additional column like following

```
name      rank   createdby
vikas      1       nitin
pravin     2       nitin
akshay     5       nitin
vijay      3       nitin
Prasad     4       nitin


Note:  name column is employee name so it is anything
```

I tried like getting in C#

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string setAnswer(string jsondata)
{
    List<string[]> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string[]>>(jsondata);
}
```

**Question.**

1) how to get this `json data` in C# and `add additional column`

2) Is it possible to pass whole data using multiple row insert in one query instead of using loop and insert single row.

Comment: What type db access are you using? EF ? ADO? NHibernate?

Comment: i am using sql server 2008

Comment: depends on the database you are using. If the db allows bulkinsert its definitly possible. to add a row to an array you have to copy the whole array.

Comment: upgrade to sql server 2016

Comment: it is possible or not  using sql server 2008 and how to do my it first question

Comment: yes to avoid for loop you can use table valued parameters
you need to convert list to datatable 
check this link https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/31/sql-server-table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server-2008/
let me know if you require more help

Comment: @Chintan Udeshi  please give example how to pass value for such procedure using C#

Comment: I assume `temp = ` is your way of saying that you have a variable with that content, not that this is part of the payload/string because this part is not legal json.

Comment: @Pravin
check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097079/c-sharp-sql-server-passing-a-list-to-a-stored-procedure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to deserialize this content:

```
{
    "Vikas": 1,
    "Pravin": 2,
    "Akshay": 5,
    "Vijay": 3,
    "Prasad": 4 
}
```

Is to deserialize it into a `Dictionary<string, int>`.

Here's a [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) example:

```
void Main()
{
    const string json = @"{
        ""Vikas"": 1,
        ""Pravin"": 2,
        ""Akshay"": 5,
        ""Vijay"": 3,
        ""Prasad"": 4
    }";
    Dictionary<string, int> empsAndNumbers =
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, int>>(json);
    empsAndNumbers.Dump();
}
```

which outputs:

[image: example output]

Answer (score 3):

Edited after explantions:

You can deserialize it to dictionary in this way:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, int>>(temp);
```

I this point we have dictionary with data. 
How to save it into DB depends how you access to db.

Comment: thanks for reply but no..no...  this is employee name so i cannot make it static it may be anything  so this is not possible to make class

Comment: A dictionary of string to int is more appropriate, `Dictionary<string, int>`.

Comment: @Pravin you don say it, this is very imprtant thing for solution. Edit question and add this info.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen with this info you are right

Comment: okk I will add in question

Answer (score 2):

Create an Entity : `MemberRank`

```
public class MemberRank
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MemberName { get; set; }
    public int Rank{ get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Then in Controller,

```
var membersText = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(envContentRootPath, @"PathOfTheFile"));
var members = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MemberRank>>(membersText);
members.ForEach(cb => cb.CreatedBy = "nitin");
_dbContext.Set<MemberRank>().AddRange(members);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

For this to work, you need to change your json file as follows:

```
[
  {
     "memberName" : "Vikas",
     "rank" : 1
  },
  {
     "memberName" : "Pravin",
     "rank" : 2
  },
  {
     "memberName" : "Akshay",
     "rank" : 5
  },
  {
     "memberName" : "Vijay",
     "rank" : 3
  },
  {
     "memberName" : "Prasad",
     "rank" : 4
  }
]
```

Comment: How do you get Json.net to deserialize the example json into your `MemberRank` type?

Comment: Where do you have in question info about EF?

Comment: I am assuming that he is using EF, Sir.