# SQL Server : pass a list of objects to stored procedure when object is a row in table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table with column_a, column_b, column_c.

I would like to pass a list of objects to a stored procedure, each object representing a row in the table.

Meaning:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertMultipleObject] 
    (@Objects List<MyEntity>)
```

`MyEntity` stores values for column_a, column_b, column_c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use Table-Valued parameters. A link here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine

In your case you need to create a custom type in database (I declared column types as INT, as an example)

```
CREATE TYPE YourTypeName AS TABLE (
    column_a INT
  , column_b INT
  , column_c INT);
```

One that's done, your procedure can be created as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertMultipleObject] (
    @Objects YourTypeName READONLY
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT *
    FROM @Objects;
END;

DECLARE @Objects YourTypeName;

INSERT INTO @Objects (column_a, column_b, column_c)
VALUES (1, 1, 1)
    , (2, 2, 2)
    , (3, 3, 3);

EXECUTE dbo.InsertMultipleObject @Objects = @Objects;
```

So this has taken a single parameter which contained multiple rows/columns as a parameter and simply made a `SELECT *` from it.

Comment: OK, but i need to pass it to the stored procedure as a list of those objects,
the way you showed allows to pass only one object.

Comment: This answer is correct. It allows you to pass a table with multiple records, because you've created a user defined table type which is used as a parameter in the procedure.
Each row in the passed table corresponds to what you refer to as an "object".

Comment: @user4675862 What Rasmus has said. Couldn't explain it any better. If you needed a single object. You simply can pass a parameter for each of your columns, that's it :)

Comment: I think I miss something here.
Indeed I need multiple records per table but the list should be of multiple tables.

Comment: Actually, try checking this out. I think it's exactly what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097079/c-sharp-sql-server-passing-a-list-to-a-stored-procedure

Comment: @user4675862 Updated. If this is not what you're looking for. Clarify your question.