# Convert this EF query to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I've got this horrible EF code in a code base and I am scratching my head trying to figure out what it's trying to do. If I were looking to put this in a stored procedure instead how would this query look in SQL?

```
public void LoadNotifyListItems(UserProfileModel user, DbContext pc)
    {
        var allowedEvents = (from r in user.Roles
                             join near in pc.NotifyEventAllowedRoles on r.RoleId equals near.RoleId
                             join ne in pc.NotifyEvents on near.NotifyEventId equals ne.Id
                             select ne).Distinct();
        var NotifyListItems = from ne in allowedEvents
                          join pune in pc.UserNotifyEvents
                          on new { NotifyEventId = ne.Id, UserId = user.Id }
                          equals new { pune.NotifyEventId, pune.UserId }
                          into loj
                          from pune in loj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          select new NotifyListItem
                          {
                              Event = ne,
                              Value = pune ?? new UserNotifyEvent
                              {
                                  NotifyEventId = ne.Id
                              }
                          };
    }
```

The issue I am having is the entirety of pc.UserNotifyEvents table is being queried. Monitoring the DB, EF is making this query when the `LoadNotifyListItems` method is being run:

```
[Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId],
[Extent1].[NotifyEventId] AS [NotifyEventId],
[Extent1].[NotifyPrimaryEmail] AS [NotifyPrimaryEmail],   
[Extent1].[NotifyAlternateEmail] AS [NotifyAlternateEmail],
[Extent1].[NotifySmsNumber] AS [NotifySmsNumber],
[Extent1].[Threshold1] AS [Threshold1],
[Extent1].[Threshold2] AS [Threshold2]
FROM [UserNotifyEvents] AS [Extent1]
```

This isn't needed and its ingesting 200,000 rows everytime. I am thinking of moving the query to a Stored Proc and pass in userId as a parameter instead

Please let me know if there is not enough information to go off here.

Comment: What's the problem with the query ? It looks not so terrible.

Comment: Step 1: get all distinct  `NotifyEvents` allowed by all `Roles` for this `user`. Then left-join all `UserNotifyEvents` for this `user` to that list and create `NotifyListItem` objects for each.

Comment: @Posio its currently querying the entire content of pc.UserNotifyEvents which is not intended. Table contains over 200,000 rows and there is no need to query for all of them.

Comment: The query you quote looks as if it is missing at least a `JOIN`.

Comment: @PeterSmith I am not too familiar with EF. However, it looks like it's querying the entire table separately and then doing joins after the query. I can reproduce the issue I am having by running the query in the LoadNotifyListItems method. Everytime we can see the troublesome query being run (fetching the entire UserNotifyEvents table).

Comment: That's not the query I would expect to see from your `linq`

Comment: Can you share the query from the profiler ? It's also important what EF Core version u use.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the query is joining a list of roles in memory (`user.Roles`) with an `IQueryable` from the DbContext. This is probably the cause of your issue. You should use the `pc.Roles` property instead, and introduce a where clause to filter by the id of the provided user.

Comment: it was a good suggestion however it still seems to query the entire table. I replaced user.Roles with pc.UserRoles

Comment: @CodeMuppet Can you show the new query and the executed sql from sql server profiler?

Answer (score 0):

### If user info is in same database as other tables

Pass the user id to the stored proc.  Inside the sproc, join user-roles to the other tables WHERE userid = passed-in parameter.

### If user info is NOT in same database as other tables

First, get a list of role ids for the user.

```
var roleIds = user.Roles.Select(i=>i.RoleId).Distinct().ToList();
```

Then you're going to pass that list of role IDs to your stored proc.  Try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097079/c-sharp-sql-server-passing-a-list-to-a-stored-procedure) Stack Overflow article, which tells you how to pass those role IDs as distinct strings to a stored proc.

The rest of this appears to be regular table joins within the database.  The most critical part is getting those roles IDs for the user.