# How to insert 1000 random dates between a given range?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am new to sql server. I  need to generate random dates selected from a given date range. 
Like the date of employment of an employee should be anywhere between `2011-01-01` and `2011-12-31`. The generated dates should be inserted into a 1000 row table randomly.

Can any one guide me with my query?

Answer (score 60):

```
declare @FromDate date = '2011-01-01'
declare @ToDate date = '2011-12-31'

select dateadd(day, 
               rand(checksum(newid()))*(1+datediff(day, @FromDate, @ToDate)), 
               @FromDate)
```

Answer (score 25):

You can simply use this query.

```
DATEADD(DAY, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 364 ), '2011-01-01')
```

If you want to add dates from a different timeline, you can change `01-01-2011` and `364`. `364` is equal to days you want to add. In this case, it's between `01-01-2011` and `31-12-2011`.
(`31-12-2011` is also included.)

---

For example, let say you want to add a random date between `2018-01-01` and `2018-01-31`, you can change the query like this.

```
DATEADD(DAY, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 31), '2018-01-01')
```

To insert (one row/date), simply use this...

```
DECLARE @rdate DATE = DATEADD(DAY, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 31), '2018-01-01')

INSERT INTO TableName ([DateColumn])
VALUES (@rdate);
```

Output

```
+-----+------------+
| ID  | DateColumn |
+-----+------------+
| 01  | 2018-01-21 |
+-----+------------+
```

Online Demo: [SQLFiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bcec9/3/1)

---

To insert 1000 rows at once...

```
DECLARE @rdate DATE
DECLARE @startLoopID INT = 1
DECLARE @endLoopID INT = 1000 -- Rows you want to add

WHILE @startLoopID <= @endLoopID
BEGIN
    SET @rdate = DATEADD(DAY, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 364 ), '2011-01-01');
    SET @startLoopID = @startLoopID + 1;

    INSERT INTO TableName ([DateColumn])
    VALUES (@rdate);
END
```

Output

```
+--------+------------+
|  ID    | DateColumn |
+--------+------------+
| 10000  | 2010-04-07 |
| 10001  | 2010-07-29 |
| 10002  | 2010-11-18 |
| 10003  | 2010-05-27 |
| 10004  | 2010-01-31 |
| 10005  | 2010-08-26 |
|   ˅    |     ˅      |
| 20000  | 2010-06-26 |
+--------+------------+
```

Online Demo: [SQLFiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bcec9/14/1)

---

To update existing rows...

```
UPDATE TableName
SET [DateColumn] = DATEADD(DAY, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 364 ), '2011-01-01')
WHERE condition;
```

Online Demo: [SQLFiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e375d/5/1)

Comment: so clean ... love solutions like that.

Answer (score 9):

I have write to you this simple function that returns a random date between date range:

```
create function date_rand ( @fromDate date, @toDate date) returns date
as
begin
 
 declare @days_between int
 declare @days_rand int

 set @days_between = datediff(day,@fromDate,@toDate)
 set @days_rand  = cast(RAND()*10000 as int)  % @days_between
 
 return dateadd( day, @days_rand, @fromDate )
end
```

to call the function:

```
select dbo.date_rand( '1/1/2001', '10/1/2001' )
```

you can combine function with a row generator:

```
;WITH Nbrs_3( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 0 ),
Nbrs_2( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_3 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_3 n2 ),
Nbrs_1( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_2 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_2 n2 ),
Nbrs_0( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_1 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_1 n2 ),
Nbrs ( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_0 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_0 n2 )
SELECT dbo.date_rand( '1/1/2001', '10/1/2001' )
FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n)
FROM Nbrs ) D ( n )
WHERE n <= 1000
```

**EDITED**

To generate random numbers use:

```
RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))
```

instead of RAND()

**EDITED II**

Function returns 'Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'rand' within a function' error. THis is because we can not use non-deterministic functions like RAND() or NEWID().

A workaround is to [create a view like](http://www.sqlpointers.com/2006/07/accessing-non-deterministic-functions.html):

```
create view myRandomNumber as 
select cast( RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*1000 as int) as new_rand
```

and then use it in function:

```
...
select @days_rand  = new_rand  % @days_between from myRandomNumber
...
```

or simple don't use the function and write expresion on select. I have write a function only yo explain step by step the solucion.

```
declare @fromdate date
declare @todate date
set @fromdate = '1/1/2001'
set @todate = '10/1/2001'
;WITH Nbrs_3( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 0 ),
Nbrs_2( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_3 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_3 n2 ),
Nbrs_1( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_2 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_2 n2 ),
Nbrs_0( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_1 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_1 n2 ),
Nbrs ( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_0 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_0 n2 )
SELECT 
   dateadd( day, 
            cast( RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*1000 as int) % 
                         datediff(day,@fromDate,@toDate), 
            @fromDate )
FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n)
FROM Nbrs ) D ( n )
WHERE n <= 1000
```

You can [test here this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/63654/new).

Comment: What version of SQL Server do  you use? I tested in SQL Server 2012 and got `Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'rand' within a function.`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I know that this is an old question, but it was linked from a newer one so... Here are my 2 cents:

1. Database tables are unsorted by nature.
2. There are only 365 possible dates in a given year, 366 if it's a leap year.
3. Duplicated data is a sign of poor design.

Based on these premises, I believe that there really is no actual need to store a 1000 random dates in a table, when it's possible to store only the relevant date and just select how many rows and in whatever order you need.

First, store the data inside the table. you can use a [Tally table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/) to create the relevant date range.
A Tally table is a table containing a sequence of numbers. for argument's sake, let's assume you already created your tally table of numbers between 0 to 1,000,000.
[You can check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393951/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-and-populate-a-numbers-table) for the best way to create one, personally I like this method:

```
-- create the tally table
SELECT TOP 100000  IDENTITY (int ,0, 1) as num 
INTO Tally 
FROM sys.sysobjects 
CROSS JOIN sys.all_columns
```

Now that you have the Tally table, it's fairly simple to create a calendar:

```
DECLARE @FromDate datetime = GETDATE(), 
        @ToDate datetime = DATEADD(YEAR, 1, GETDATE()) -- a year from now in my example

;With CalendarCTE AS
(
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, num, @FromDate) As caneldarDate 
FROM Tally
WHERE num < DATEDIFF(DAY, @FromDate, @ToDate) 
)
```

Now that you have the calendar and the tally table, it's fairly simple to use them both to get any number of records in any order you want.
A thousand randomly-ordered dates? no problem:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 caneldarDate
FROM CalendarCTE c
CROSS JOIN Tally t 
WHERE t.num < 1000
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Full script, including creating and dropping the tally table took less then a second to execute:

```
-- create the tally table
SELECT TOP 100000  IDENTITY (int ,0, 1) as num 
INTO Tally 
FROM sys.sysobjects 
CROSS JOIN sys.all_columns

-- crealte the calendar cte:
DECLARE @FromDate datetime = GETDATE(), 
        @ToDate datetime = DATEADD(YEAR, 1, GETDATE())

;With CalendarCTE AS
(
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, num, @FromDate) As caneldarDate 
FROM Tally
WHERE num < DATEDIFF(DAY, @FromDate, @ToDate) 
)

-- select a 1000 random dates
SELECT TOP 1000 caneldarDate
FROM CalendarCTE c
CROSS JOIN Tally t 
WHERE t.num < 1000
ORDER BY NEWID()

-- cleanup
DROP TABLE Tally
```

Comment: Dude, there are 365 days in a year, not 356 :D

Comment: Meh!  There are very definitely 8 days in my week, or so my boss would have me believe...