# Random date between two given dates SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to follow one of the answers given in

[How to insert 1000 random dates between a given range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645348/how-to-insert-1000-random-dates-between-a-given-range)

and used the following code to create a function:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION RandomDate (@fromDate DATE, @toDate DATE) 
RETURNS DATE
AS 
BEGIN
   declare @days_between int
   declare @days_rand int

   set @days_between = datediff(day,@fromDate,@toDate)
   set @days_rand  = cast(RAND()*10000 as int)  % @days_between

   return dateadd(day, @days_rand, @fromDate)
end
```

When I try to create the function, I get the following error:

> Msg 443, Level 16, State 1, Procedure RandomDate, Line 7
>   Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'rand' within a function.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: RAND() function is directly not allowed to use in the UDF. http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/11/20/sql-server-using-rand-in-user-defined-functions-udf/

Comment: Must it be a UDF? can't you use a stored procedure for that?

Comment: could it be a function that would calls sp?

Comment: Sp cannot be called from function..

Answer (score 0):

Create a view using the rand function

```
  CREATE VIEW randomView
    AS
    SELECT RAND() randomResult
    GO
```

Use the view in the function created.

```
 create function RandomDate ( @fromDate date, @toDate date) returns date AS 
BEGIN
 declare @days_between int
 declare @days_rand int

  declare @rndResult int

 select @rndResult=randomResultfrom randomView

 set @days_between = datediff(day,@fromDate,@toDate)
 set @days_rand  = cast(@rndResult*10000 as int)  % @days_between

 return dateadd( day, @days_rand, @fromDate )
end
```

Comment: could it be a function that would calls sp? for a reason, I do not want to use views.