# finding a mismatch while iterating rows in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this issue where date keys where just inserted into a table through SQL Server.  They are populated iteratively in the fashion shown below:

- 20130501
- 20130502
- 20130503
- ...

I am currently trying to find any row where one of the dates was skipped, i.e:

- 20130504
- **20130506**
- 20130507

I'm still a rookie in SQL Server and I have looked at CURSOR but I'm having some trouble understanding how to go about about querying this.  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using some tricks from the Itzik Ben-Gan school of thought. The easiest way to find gaps is with the use of a tally table. Here is a way to create a small one into a table variable, but i would recommend creating a substantiated Numbers table because they're really handy for this kind of thing. You can find a bunch of examples on how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393951/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-and-populate-a-numbers-table).

#### First create a number table

```
DECLARE @Numbers TABLE ( [Number] INT );

    INSERT  INTO @Numbers
    (
      Number
    )
    SELECT TOP 1000
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [s1].[object_id]) AS Number
    FROM    sys.objects s1
    CROSS JOIN sys.objects s2
```

#### Next I needed to create a temp table to recreate your example

```
DECLARE @ExampleDates TABLE ( [RecordDateKey] INT );

INSERT  INTO @ExampleDates
    ( [RecordDateKey] )
VALUES  ( 20130501 ),
        ( 20130502 ),
        ( 20130503 ),
        ( 20130504 ),
        ( 20130506 ),
        ( 20130507 ),
        ( 20130508 ),
        ( 20130511 );
```

*this syntax only works 2008-r2 and forward but since i'm just staging data it's not really a big deal. Just leaving this note for other people testing this example.*

#### Finally we need to do some conversion work.

For larger sets, it might be beneficial to substantiate this data, but for this small example, a cte sufficed.

```
WITH    date_convert
      AS (
           SELECT   [RecordDateKey]
                  , CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST([RecordDateKey] AS VARCHAR(50)), 112) [RecordDate]
           FROM     @ExampleDates ed
         ) ,
    date_range
      AS (
           SELECT   DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN([RecordDate]), MAX([RecordDate])) [Range]
                  , MIN([RecordDate]) [StartDate]
           FROM     [date_convert]
         ) ,
    all_dates
      AS (
           SELECT   CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(DAY, num.[Number], [StartDate]), 112)) AS [RecordDateKey]
                  , DATEADD(DAY, num.[Number], [StartDate]) [RecordDate]
           FROM     @Numbers num
           CROSS JOIN [date_range] dr
           WHERE    num.[Number] <= dr.[Range]
         )
 SELECT [RecordDateKey]
      , [RecordDate]
 FROM   all_dates ad
 WHERE  NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                     FROM   [date_convert] dc
                     WHERE  ad.[RecordDate] = dc.RecordDate )
```

- date_convert: changes the key you provided to a datetime for easy comparison and for dateadd.
- date_range: finds the range of dates, and where the range starts.
- all_dates: finds all of the dates that should have existed in your range.
- The final select finds the records in the data that aren't in the generated set.

Using this code, this was my output. This should find gaps regardless of gap size. Which appeared to be the issue with the current accepted answer.

```
RecordDateKey   RecordDate
-------------   ----------
20130505        2013-05-05 00:00:00.000
20130509        2013-05-09 00:00:00.000
20130510        2013-05-10 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: An easy way to play with this example, check out this fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2ab1e/1/0

Comment: Thank you for building up on the previous answer this is great!

Comment: Glad that the answer was able to help. I just needed to solve a problem like this so I still had the queries on hand.

Comment: The fiddle no longer works because of age, here is an updated one in case this example is still helpful for people. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/169fb/1

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE date - 1 NOT IN (SELECT date FROM table)
```

It's probably not super efficient but it should work.

Comment: So, what happens when the gap is of two (or more) consecutive days?

Comment: It would still work. A gap of x (>1) days still contains a gap of one day. The only problem with this is that the very first entry will always be returned.

Comment: I think that the fact that only the first entry is returned is a problem and doesn't completely answer op's question

Comment: Thank you very much Jean-Bernard!