# Spliting large string in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using this logic to split the string query

```
declare @query nvarchar(max)

set @query = '1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14'

SELECT SUBSTRING('&' + @query + '&', Number + 1,     -- is used to split the '@query'   on the basis of '&' sign         
    CHARINDEX('&', '&' + @query + '&', Number + 1) - Number -1)AS VALUE                
    FROM master..spt_values                
    WHERE Type = 'P'                
    AND Number <= LEN('&' + @query + '&') - 1                
    AND SUBSTRING('&' + @query + '&', Number, 1) = '&'
```

It works fine when query is small, but its giving me less result then actual when the value of @query is very large

For eg.

```
@query = 'very large string containing 60 & sign '
```

returns only 10 records

How can I split large string, and what is the reason? Why can `SUBSTRING` not handle large strings?

Comment: Is the string longer than 2048 characters? (`master..spt_values` has 2048 rows where `Type = 'P'`. If your string is longer than 2048 characters, the remainder may be ignored.)

Comment: @ITBeginner: yes, i want only split by & sign and its very large string

Comment: @EdHarper: it may be larger then 2048, then how can i split large string

Comment: A typical solution is to `CROSS JOIN` `spt_values` to itself, using a `row_number()` function to generate the sequential values for `Number`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1394093/27825. Answers to that question provide several other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7938/SQL-User-Defined-Function-to-Parse-a-Delimited-Str) function. It returns a table of splitted values, based on input string and a delimeter.

Usage:

```
select * 
from dbo.fn_ParseText2Table('1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14','&')
```

The function has a parameter `@p_SourceText` which type is `varchar(8000)`, so input string can be up to 8000 characters.

You can change type to `varchar(max)` if version of your SQL Server allows you to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I used this Function and its working for me Perfectly :)

```
 CREATE function f_split(@SourceSql nvarchar(Max),@StrSeprate varchar(10))
returns @temp 
table([column] nvarchar(Max))
begin    
 declare @i int    
 set @SourceSql=rtrim(ltrim(@SourceSql)) 
 set @i=charindex(@StrSeprate,@SourceSql)    
 while @i>=1    
 begin        
  insert @temp values(left(@SourceSql,@i-1))        
  set @SourceSql=substring(@SourceSql,@i+1,len(@SourceSql)-@i)        
  set @i=charindex(@StrSeprate,@SourceSql)    
 end    
 if @SourceSql<>'\'       
 insert @temp values(@SourceSql)    
 return 
end
go

    select * from dbo.f_split('1,2,3,4,5',',')
    go
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why your code is not getting the result. I executed the query with large amount of data. But I got the result. May be your string is very much bigger than I did the testing. I have also the same requirement to split the string. I am using this function to get the solution. You can try this.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] ( @MyArray VARCHAR(8000), @separator CHAR(1) ) 
    RETURNS @RetTable TABLE 
    (StrValue VARCHAR(256))
AS

BEGIN
DECLARE @SeperatorString VARCHAR(10);
SET @SeperatorString = '%' + @separator + '%'
DECLARE @separator_position INT 
DECLARE @array_value VARCHAR(1000) 
SET @MyArray = @MyArray + @separator
WHILE PATINDEX( @SeperatorString , @MyArray) <> 0 
BEGIN
    SELECT @separator_position =  PATINDEX(@SeperatorString , @MyArray)
    SELECT @array_value = LEFT(@MyArray, @separator_position - 1)
    INSERT @RetTable VALUES ( CAST(@array_value AS VARCHAR(256)) )
    SELECT @MyArray = STUFF(@MyArray, 1, @separator_position, '')
END

RETURN
```

END

If you want more explanation on this function, how the function is using and what the parameters are , you can take a look [here.](http://dotnetpebbles.blogspot.in/2013/09/how-to-split-string-in-sql-server.html?view=flipcard). This is very simple function and easy to use.