# SQL Query to show attendance between two dates

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

I've got a .Net application with an attendance table which has fields for a Start and End date. I'm struggling to show a graph of attendance for a given period. I can easily find how many rows are applicable on any given day using between but I can't get my head around pivoting results so that I can graph a count of rows per day. I could run a SQL query for every day individually and then graph the results but is there any way of doing this with T-SQL that I could then use to graph with?

Edit:-

Apologies as this is the first time I've asked a question here, but as huMpty duMpty has stated the question probably needs more clarification. I've got both a startdate and enddate column in the sql db and I need to count per day if the range between these dates falls between the range of the selection criteria. e.g if I've got a start date of 2013-01-01 and end date 2013-01-10 and I report on a period of 2013-01-09 to 2013-01-11 then i'm looking at getting a result for 1 for 2013-01-09 and 1 for 2013-01-10... Hope this make more sense and thanks for your assistance

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Removed my answer as I didn't spot the start vs end date in the question

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a table with start and end dates; for a given date range, you would like to know the given number of records that fall on each date.

I believe this problem may be solved with a numbers table. I created a numbers table on the fly in a stored procedure, but I recommend creating a permanent numbers table in your production code. Here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/50d32/1).

```
Create Table Attendance (
  id int primary key identity(1,1) not null
  ,start_date date not null
  ,end_date date not null
);
Go

Insert Attendance(start_date, end_date)
Values ('1/1/2013', '1/10/2013')
,('1/10/2013', '1/15/2013')
,('2/20/2013', '3/1/2013');
Go

-- Create numbers table. See: Method 3 of http://stackoverflow.com/a/1407488/772086
With Numbers(Number) As
(
  Select 1 As Number
  Union All
  Select Number + 1 From Numbers Where Number < 10000
)

Select 
  AttendanceDate = Convert(date, DateAdd(day,Numbers.number, '1/1/2000'))
  ,AttendanceCount = Count(*)
From dbo.Attendance
  Join Numbers
  On Numbers.Number
    Between DateDiff(day, '1/1/2000', Attendance.start_date) 
    And DateDiff(day, '1/1/2000', Attendance.end_date)
-- Reporting range between 1/9 and 1/11
Where DateAdd(day,Numbers.number, '1/1/2000') Between '1/9/2013' 
  And '1/11/2013'
Group By Convert(date, DateAdd(day,Numbers.number, '1/1/2000'))
Option(MaxRecursion 10000);
```

All dates are in US format (m/d/yy) - you may want to switch those to the internationalized standard (yyyy-mm-dd) in your production code.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much for the help. The numbers table was definitely the missing piece I needed to get this working. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You said you wanted a count by day in a date range.  That can be done with a `COUNT` with a GROUP BY clause.

I don't know your schema, but a solution might look like this:

```
declare @MyTable table
(
    ID int identity(1,1) primary key clustered,
    MyDate smalldatetime
)
insert into @MyTable (MyDate)
values
    ('2012-12-31'), -- before the date range, so not included in results
    ('2013-01-10'),
    ('2013-01-10'), -- appears twice
    ('2013-01-11'), -- appears once
    ('2013-01-12')  -- after the date range, so not included in results

select * from @MyTable

select
    MyDate,
    count(*)
from @MyTable
where MyDate between '2013-01-09' and '2013-01-11'
group by MyDate
```