# Select non-existing rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

Let say I have a table:

```
ColumnA       ColumnB
---------------------------------
1             10.75
4             1234.30
6             2000.99
```

How can I write a SELECT query that will result in the following:

```
ColumnA    ColumnB
---------------------------------
1             10.75
2             0.00
3             0.00
4             1234.30
5             0.00
6             2000.99
```

Comment: Are you using Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Yes my friend, I noted that in the tags.

Comment: Those tags didn't exist when I first looked at the question, so thanks for updating.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a CTE to create a list of numbers from 1 to the maximum value in your table:

```
; with  numbers as
        (
        select  max(ColumnA) as nr
        from    YourTable
        union all
        select  nr - 1
        from    numbers
        where   nr > 1
        )
select  nr.nr as ColumnA
,       yt.ColumnB
from    numbers nr
left join
        YourTable yt
on      nr.nr = yt.ColumnA
order by
        nr.nr
option  (maxrecursion 0)
```

[See it working at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8b347/1/0)

Comment: So the only change needed is `yt.ColumnB` to `ISNULL(yt.ColumnB, 0)`. What a fantastic query!

Comment: @Andomar Sorry for the late reply, I just think waiting a bit helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
declare @min int, @max int
select @min=MIN(ColumnA), @max=MAX(ColumnA) from tbl

select 
    distinct number ColumnA, 
    isnull(b.ColumnB, 0) ColumnB
from 
    master.dbo.spt_values a left join tbl b on a.number=b.ColumnA
where number between @min and @max
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a TallyTable (or NumbersTable) - see this question: [What is the best way to create and populate a numbers table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393951/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-and-populate-a-numbers-table)

With that table create an insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO YourTable (ColumnA, ColumnB)
SELECT Number FROM NumberTable
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM YourTable WHERE NumberTable.Number = YourTable.ColumnA)
    -- Adjust this value or calculate it with a query to the maximum of the source table
    AND NumberTable.Number < 230130
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (ID INT,Val DECIMAL(10,2))
INSERT INTO @t (ID,Val) VALUES (1,10.75)
INSERT INTO @t (ID,Val) VALUES (4,6.75)
INSERT INTO @t (ID,Val) VALUES (7,4.75)
declare @MinNo int
declare @MaxNo int
declare @IncrementStep int
set @MinNo = 1
set @MaxNo = 10
set @IncrementStep = 1

;with C as
(
  select @MinNo as Num
  union all 
  select Num + @IncrementStep
  from C 
  where Num < @MaxNo
)      
select Num,
CASE WHEN Val IS NOT NULL THEN Val ELSE 0.00 END AS NUMBER
from C  
LEFT JOIN @t t
ON t.ID = c.Num
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a number-table or following trick to generate a sequence which you can  `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with your table. I assume you want to determine the boundaries dynamically:

```
WITH Seq AS 
(
    SELECT TOP ((SELECT Max(ColumnA)FROM Table1) - (SELECT Min(ColumnA) FROM Table1) + 1) 
        Num = (SELECT Min(ColumnA) FROM Table1)+ Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) -1
    FROM   sys.all_objects) 
SELECT ColumnA = Seq.Num,
       ColumnB = COALESCE(t.ColumnB ,0.00)
FROM   Seq 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 t
    ON Seq.Num = t.ColumnA
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/19d03/1/0) with your sample.

Worth reading: http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1

Answer (score 0):

I have my collect of table functions like these.

```
create function dbo.GetNumbers(@Start int, @End int)
returns @Items table
(
    Item int
)
as 
begin

    while (@Start <= @End)
    begin 
        insert into @Items
        values (@Start)

        set @Start = @Start + 1
    end 

    return

end
```

Then I can use it to left join to my data table and every value will be there.

```
declare @min int, @max int
set @min = 10
set @max = 20


select gn.Item
from dbo.GetNumbers(@min, @max) gn
```

I have similar table functions for date ranges, times, timezones, etc.