# HierarchyID: Get all descendants for a list of parents — Not Working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working off this thread: HierarchyID: [HierarchyID: Get all descendants for a list of parents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25079528/hierarchyid-get-all-descendants-for-a-list-of-parents)

I have a table that uses a HierarchyID, and I need a query that gives me all descendants for specified parent(s) in a single set.

Here's my table, populated:

```
DECLARE @Ph TABLE (ProductHierarchyNode HIERARCHYID, ProductHierarchyId INT)
INSERT INTO @Ph (ProductHierarchyNode, ProductHierarchyId) VALUES 
(hierarchyid::Parse('/1/'), 1),
(hierarchyid::Parse('/1/1/'), 2),
(hierarchyid::Parse('/1/1/2/'), 3),
(hierarchyid::Parse('/1/1/2/1/'), 4)
```

This query works perfectly for a SINGLE id: 4. It gives me back that item, plus all of its descendants.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    @Ph
WHERE 
    (SELECT ProductHierarchyNode FROM @Ph WHERE ProductHierarchyId = 4).IsDescendantOf(ProductHierarchyNode) = 1
```

[image]

However, that query isn't very useful for a list of ID's. So for a list, I'm trying the answer in the thread I linked to above:

```
SELECT 
    child.*
FROM 
    @Ph as parent
    INNER JOIN @Ph as child on child.ProductHierarchyNode.IsDescendantOf(parent.ProductHierarchyNode) = 1
WHERE 
    parent.ProductHierarchyId in (4)
```

I'm sure I'm overlooking something obvious. Just not sure what it is. But this only returns me the parent item and no children.

[image]

Can't spot my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like you have this backwards... you want DESCENDENTS, but you're asking for things where the parent is 4... nothing has a parent of 4.

Don't you really want this?

```
SELECT 
    child.*
FROM 
    @Ph as parent
    INNER JOIN @Ph as child on child.ProductHierarchyNode.IsDescendantOf(parent.ProductHierarchyNode) = 1
WHERE 
    parent.ProductHierarchyId in (1)
```

This returns all the rows you say you're expecting, and makes more sense to me as you're asking for all descendent of 1 (the root parent). 2 is a child/descendent of 1, 3 is a child/descendent of 2, and 4 is a child/descendent of 3.

The "WHERE parent.ProductHierarchyId IN (1)" is saying "find me all nodes where 1 is a parent/ancestor".

In the first query, you're asking for all nodes where 4 is a descendent, so that makes sense.

In the second query, you're asking for all descendents of 1.  If you want "all ancestors of 4" that'd be a different query.

Comment: I think you are right. I think I need to be asking for Ancestors of 4.