# SQL select everything in date range with multiple values for each date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I've tried searching but I'm not entirely sure how to word it so apologies in advance if this has already been answered elsewhere.

I am trying to select Everything between a date range (Including where there is no value for that date) for mutiple values. I havent really explained very weel but below is an example of the ouput I am after.

```
Date    Campaign    Channel Transaction
01/01/2015  a   Online  Sale
01/01/2015  b   Online  Sale
01/01/2015  c   Online  Sale
01/01/2015  a   Online  Cancellation
01/01/2015  b   Online  Cancellation
01/01/2015  c   Online  Cancellation
01/01/2015  a   Offline Sale
01/01/2015  b   Offline Sale
01/01/2015  c   Offline Sale
01/01/2015  a   Offline Cancellation
01/01/2015  b   Offline Cancellation
01/01/2015  c   Offline Cancellation
02/01/2015  a   Online  Sale
02/01/2015  b   Online  Sale
02/01/2015  c   Online  Sale
02/01/2015  a   Online  Cancellation
02/01/2015  b   Online  Cancellation
02/01/2015  c   Online  Cancellation
02/01/2015  a   Offline Sale
02/01/2015  b   Offline Sale
02/01/2015  c   Offline Sale
02/01/2015  a   Offline Cancellation
02/01/2015  b   Offline Cancellation
02/01/2015  c   Offline Cancellation
```

I am able to select every day between a date range however cannot work out how to select every day with every outcome even if no results are returned.

Edit - Added solution I found

OK, So I have a solution which seems to be working for me. There may be a better way of doing this and any suggestions are appreciated but here is what I am now doing

```
Declare @CC TABLE (Campaign varchar(50))
DECLARE @Channel Table (Channel Varchar(255))
DECLARE @TYPE TABLE (Transaction_Type varchar(255))
Insert Into @CC (Campaign) Values ('1')
Insert Into @CC (Campaign) Values ('2')
Insert Into @Channel (Channel) Values ('Online')
Insert Into @Channel (Channel) Values ('Inbound')
Insert Into @TYPE (Transaction_Type) Values ('Sale')
Insert Into @TYPE (Transaction_Type) Values ('Cancellation')
DECLARE 
@StartDate DATE = Dateadd(YY,-3,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0)), 
@EndDate DATE = Getdate() 
SELECT 
DATEADD(DAY, nbr - 1, @StartDate) as Dates,
Campaign, 
Channel, 
Transaction_Type 
FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY c.object_id ) AS Nbr  
FROM sys.columns c) nbrs,
@CC, @Channel, @TYPE WHERE nbr - 1 <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate)
Order by Dates asc, Campaign asc, Channel asc, Transaction_Type asc
```

Comment: I have currently used the following code to create a static table. This will be something that will be needed again so thought made sense to have a static table. `CREATE TABLE _Dates (
  d DATE,
  PRIMARY KEY (d)
)
DECLARE @dIncr DATE = '2000-01-01'
DECLARE @dEnd DATE = '2100-01-01'

WHILE ( @dIncr < @dEnd )
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO _Dates (d) VALUES( @dIncr )
  SELECT @dIncr = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @dIncr )
END`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a CTE.

```
  DECLARE
    @start date = '1900-01-01',
    @end date = '1900-01-10';

with dateRange (myDate) AS (
    select @start myDate
    UNION ALL
    select DATEADD(DAY,1,myDate) from dateRange
    where
        myDate <= @end
)
select 
    * 
from dateRange D
inner join yourTable T on
    D.myDate = T.[Date]
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 365)
```

With the full outer joins

```
DECLARE
    @start date = '1900-01-01',
    @end date = '1900-01-10';

with dateRange (myDate) AS (
    select @start myDate
    UNION ALL
    select DATEADD(DAY,1,myDate) from dateRange
    where
        myDate <= @end
)
select 
    * 
from dateRange D
full outer join @CC C ON
    1=1
full outer join @Channel CH ON
    1=1
full outer join @TYPE Ty ON
    1=1
left join yourTable T on
    D.myDate = T.[Date] and
    C.Campaign = T.[Campaign] and
    CH.Channel = T.[Channel] and
    Ty.[Transaction_Type] = T.[Transaction_Type]
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 365)
```

Comment: Was just busy with that. +1 for you

Comment: This is what I'm currently using to get the date values returned. I cannot work out how to return the date for every possible outcome though. e.g I need 1st jan to return for Every Campaign, every possible Transaction type and every Sales Channel. Do i need a to create the table with a line for every outcome and join this to my dataset?

Comment: full outer join with your campaign table and only then join your results

Answer (score 0):

With pure SQL (and without recursive CTEs), I'm afraid you will need [a numbers table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1393951/87698) for that.

The basic idea will be to:

- determine `n`, the number of dates between your start and your end dates,
- select the number 1 to `n` from your numbers table, and
- add the numbers (as days) to the start date.

This should yield a list of dates from your start to your end date, which you can outer join to your original result set to "fill the gaps".

Answer (score 0):

I am using Table Valued Function that returns all dates in a range ([here](http://www.sqlblog.lv/2010/10/piemers-funkcija-lai-iegutu-datumus.html))..

You could do small changes (like renaming, datetime -> date, remove char column) to fit your needs.

```
Create Function [dbo].[IntervalaDatumi]
(
    @DatumsNo DateTime,
    @DatumsLidz DateTime
)
Returns @tab Table
    (
        Datums DateTime,
        DatumsChar char(10)
    )
As
Begin
    Declare @Dienas int
    Declare @i int
    Set @Dienas = DateDiff(Day, @DatumsNo, @DatumsLidz)

    Set @i = 0;
    While (@Dienas > @i)
    Begin
        Insert Into @tab(Datums, DatumsChar)
            Values (DateAdd(Day, @i, @DatumsNo), Convert(Char(10), DateAdd(Day, @i, @DatumsNo), 104))
        Set @i = @i + 1
    End
    return
End
```