# SQL Server : how to detect unregarded values from a range of integers

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a problem, in example: I have a range of ids of integers (from 1 to 1000), this range supposed to be ids in a SQL Server table, and I want to detect which numbers of this range are not in the table, and sorry for my bad english, thank you

Comment: what about this solution in c#:first load table from sql into a c#  data table then using a for loop check range one by one and save unregarded id's in an array

Comment: i just need to one more reputation to vote all you up,sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another simpler option would be to use the following query

```
SELECT number 
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE number BETWEEN 1 AND 1000
 AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
                  FROM Your_Table t    --<-- your table where you are checking
                  WHERE t.ID = number)    -- the missing values 
GROUP BY number
```

The above solution is only good if you are looking for around 1000 values. For more values you would need to modify it little bit, something like

```
-- Select the maximum number or IDs you want to check 
DECLARE @Max_Num INT = 10000;

;WITH CTE AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (@Max_Num) ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) numbers 
  FROM master..spt_values v1 cross join master..spt_values v2
) 
SELECT c.numbers 
FROM CTE c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM Your_table t
                  WHERE t.ID = c.numbers)
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like one of the many scenarios where it is helpful to have a numbers table:

```
SELECT *
FROM lkp_Numbers a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM YourTable b
                  WHERE a.num = b.Id)
  AND num <= 1000
```

I use this to create a numbers table:

```
DROP TABLE lkp_Numbers
DECLARE @RunDate datetime 
SET @RunDate=GETDATE()
SELECT TOP 1000 IDENTITY(int,1,1) AS Num
    INTO lkp_Numbers
    FROM sys.objects s1, sys.objects s2, sys.objects s3
ALTER TABLE lkp_Numbers ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Numbers PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Num)
```

That method for creating a numbers table was found here: [What is the best way to create and populate a numbers table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393951/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-and-populate-a-numbers-table)

Answer (score 1):

One way to find "holes" is to generate a list of all possible values and then look for the ones that aren't there.  If you can survive with a list of a missing value and then the number of subsequent values following it, you can do this with another method.

SQL Server 2012+ supports `lead()` and `lag()`.  The following gets almost everything, except for initial missing values:

```
select t.id + 1 as missingid,
       (coalesce(t.nextid, 1000) - t.id - 1) as nummissing
from (select t.*, lead(t.id) over (order by t.id) as nextid
      from table t
      t.id between 1 and 1000 
     ) t
where t.nextid > t.id + 1 or
      (t.nextid is null and t.id <> 1000)
```

You can get these with a little piece of special logic:

```
select (case when t.previd is null then 1
             else t.id + 1
        end) as missingid,
       (case when t.previd is null then t.id - 1
             else (coalesce(t.nextid, 1000) - t.id - 1) 
        end) as nummissing
from (select t.*, lead(t.id) over (order by t.id) as nextid,
             lag(t.id) over (order by t.id) as previd
      from table t
      where t.id between 1 and 1000 and
     ) t
where (t.nextid > t.id + 1 or
       (t.nextid is null and t.id <> 1000)
       (t.previd is null and t.id <> 1)
      )
```