# Good practice to use spt_values as a source of consecutive integers?

Tags: sql-server

Is it considered a good practice to use the undocumented `spt_values` table in SQL Server as a source of consecutive numbers?

Is there a risk that this could break in a future release of SQL Server or it safe as long as you don't care about portability?

I have been burned by using undocumented functions in Oracle before (`wm_concat` specifically) so my specific question is the likelihood that `spt_values` will continue to be supported in future SQL Server versions.

Comment: It is not docummented and could break your code after any upgrade. In production you should avoid it.

Comment: The next thing is the number of rows in this table, if in future someone deletes some entries you will get smaller range (if you do not use multiple `CROSS JOIN`). Today it is `2523` what if it will be only `100`?

Comment: [Add a built-in table of numbers](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/258733) still open :)

Comment: Several good answers on what to choose to make tally tables [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1393951/243373)