# SQL loop with a column number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table with 3 col and 4 row.

```
        Col1    Col2    Col3
Row1    A1      B1      1
Row2    A2      B2      0
Row3    A3      B3      3
Row4    A4      B4      1
```

A `select * from [table]` returns:

```
A1 B1 1
A2 B2 0
A3 B3 3
A4 B4 1
```

I Want a select that give:

```
A1 B1 1
A3 B3 3 
A3 B3 3
A3 B3 3
A4 B4 1
```

Col3 gives the number of row return.

Comment: Also known as smeacol.

Comment: `ORDER BY` inside the SQL

Answer (score 5):

Start with a numbers table... a table with one row for each number, going up as high as the largest possible value in your `Col3`. It will look something like this:

**Table: Numbers**

```
Value
-----
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  ...
```

Then you you can `JOIN` to this table using an inequality:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM [table] t
INNER JOIN NUMBERS n ON n.Value <= t.Col3
```

This will make your Row3 value match to the `Numbers` table 3 times, duplicating that row in the results, whereas the Row2 value won't match any records from the Numbers table, removing it from the results.

There are several options for generating a `Numbers` table you can look at here:

> [What is the best way to create and populate a numbers table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393951/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-and-populate-a-numbers-table)

With the Option 6 from that question:

```
WITH Numbers AS (
     SELECT TOP 10000 row_number() over(order by t1.number) as [Value]
     FROM master..spt_values t1 
     CROSS JOIN master..spt_values t2
)
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM [table] t
INNER JOIN NUMBERS n ON n.Value <= t.Col3
```

Note that this is overkill for your sample data, which only goes to `3`. For anything less than about 50, you could just hard-code the table. I'm assuming your real data goes much higher.

Comment: I was thinking ,how to do with numbers table and here is the answer.Nice one

Comment: If your numbers table has a 0, you'll want your comparison operator to be n.Value < t.Col3.  Otherwise you will end up with extra records.

Comment: This is true, though both the sample table and the sample code I posted start with 1.