# How to select multi row not from table

Tags: t-sql

I want select multi records for serial number, like :

```
select * from 
(
    select 11 as COMP_NO
    union
    select 12
    union
    select 13
    union
    select 14
    union
    select 15
) A
```

If I want to select 100 records or more, Is there a better way ?

Comment: What is the table from which you are selecting multiple times in the `UNION`?  You might be able to use something like `SELECT * FROM ... WHERE col IN ('l1', 'l2', ...)`

Comment: I want to insert multi records into an empty table, like initial process.

Comment: Can you please show us some table structure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to create and populate a numbers table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393951/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-and-populate-a-numbers-table)

Comment: It is very simple table, I want to use t-SQL inert 10 or 100 records. 
CREATE TABLE dbo.SYSCOMP(
 COMP_NO varchar(4) NOT NULL,
 COMP_NAME nvarchar(64) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_SYSCOMP PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([COMP_NO] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: You mean like `select Comp_No from ( values (11), (12), (13), (14), (15) ) as SerialNumbers( Comp_No )`?

Comment: [Generate a set or sequence without loops](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)

Answer (score 0):

I find another way to solve my problem, create a user-defined function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SerialTable]
(
    @BeginNo int
    , @EndNo int
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    WITH MySerial(SNO, ENO)
    AS(
        SELECT @BeginNo AS SNO, @EndNo as ENO 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT SNO+1, ENO
        FROM MySerial
        WHERE SNO<ENO
    )
    SELECT SNO
    FROM MySerial
)
```

then can select 10 or more records easily

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.SerialTable(11, 20);
SELECT * FROM dbo.SerialTable(11, 100);
```