# Populate database column with dates for a specified year

Tags: c#, sql, database

I'm looking to modify information held within a database depending on the year selected by the user on a form.

Essentially if they select 2016 from a drop down list then the column in the database (labelled date) will be filled with dates from 1st Jan to 31st Dec.

I'm sure its a trivial questions but thanks!

Comment: What flavour of SQL are you using? MS SQL Server/mySQL/Oracle/Other?

Comment: I believe its a Microsoft SQL server (taken from the type information in the properties window) @JohnHC

Comment: SELECT Column_Name FROM Tabel_Name
   YEAR(date) = 2009

Answer (score 0):

Ok...

First, get a numbers table. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393951/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-and-populate-a-numbers-table) will help.

Second, select from the numbers table:

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, numbercolumn-1, CAST(YearPick +'-01-01' as DATETIME)) as datesinyear
FROM numberstable
WHERE DATEPART(yyyy,DATEADD(dd, numbercolumn-1, CAST(YearPick +'-01-01' as DATETIME))) = cast(YearPick as INT)
```

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @year VARCHAR(10) = '2016'

;with months (date)
AS
(
    SELECT cast(@year+'-01-01' as date)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(month,1,date)
    from months
    where DATEADD(month,1,date)<=CAST(getdate() as date)
)
select Datename(month,date) [Month] from months