# Counting date interval on each minutes (Tracking numbers of calls on each minutes)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Working on SQL server (Azure)
I have my table of StartCalls and EndCalls (date + time). 
I would like to build a digramme who count on each minutes the number of    calls that were made (Tracking numbers of calls on each minutes)

My solution should be build on my CountTable

**CountTable**

```
MinutStart, 
MinuteEnd, 
Range(1 to 60), 
callsnumber
```

It should be handle all the minutes included on one hour

```
00:00:00-00:00:01 1 number, 
00:00:01-00:00:02 2 number, 
...
```

And

```
Where ( StartCalls > MinutStart ) 
        and ( EndCalls < MinutEnd ) 
UPDATE Callsnumber = Callsnumber+1
```

Hope somebody has matched this issues and could help ^^

Comment: The issue is about the calls that can "overflow" the next hour... No idea for building my history who's counting on each minutes all the calls that are running

Comment: please show current data and expected data

Comment: That's all my Inpout :
>
>CDR_TIME CDR_DATE CDR_DURATION
>11:57:43 AM 02/08/2016 0:01:58
>2:05:47 PM 02/08/2016 0:00:48
>2:06:57 PM 02/08/2016 0:00:50
>4:25:17 PM 02/08/2016 0:01:48
>6:03:47 AM 04/08/2016 0:05:13
>7:05:50 AM 04/08/2016 0:01:27
>7:35:15 AM 04/08/2016 0:01:38
>10:09:41 AM 04/08/2016 0:02:12
>10:58:08 AM 04/08/2016 0:00:27
And I expected to full in my CountingTable by incrementing each field

Comment: Expected data : incrementing each 60 fields of CountingTable when there is a running call ( so I have to browse a big history )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I would rather go for a view.

Pre-requisite :
create a Number table, which would store number from 1 to xxx

see for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393951/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-and-populate-a-numbers-table)

Than, the idea would be to calculate the duration of your calls.
You could then have a starting minute, and whild the call is not at this end, you calculate the next minute and increment by a number.

Of course, you make a modulo 60 to avoid "hours overflow" problem.

You may of course do something better, but you've got the idea.

```
with calls as( 
 select
  (datepart(minute, startDate) + number -1) % 60 as min1, 
  (datepart(minute, startDate) + number) % 60 as min2, 
  datediff(minute, startDate, endDate) as duration,
  number
 from <YourTable>
 join Numbers n on n.Number <= datediff(minute, startDate, endDate)
)
select 
  min1, 
  min2, 
  count(*) as nbOfCalls
from calls
group by min1, min2
order by min1, min2
```

**EDIT**

If you need the detail by year/month/hour/minute, you could do

Create a calendar table, with all minutes, starting on 2016-06-01 in this case (and ending in 2024 in this case).

```
SELECT TOP 5000000 N=IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1)
INTO dbo.Numbers
FROM master.dbo.syscolumns a CROSS JOIN master.dbo.syscolumns  b;

ALTER TABLE dbo.Numbers ADD CONSTRAINT NBR_pk PRIMARY KEY(N);


select minutes = dateAdd(MINUTE, N, '2015-06-01')
into CalendarTable
from Numbers;
```

Now you can just do

```
select  
  ct.minutes, 
  count(t.startDate) from 
CalendarTable ct
left join <yourTable> t on ct.minutes BETWEEN DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, 0, t.startDate), 0) 
                  AND DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, 0,t.EndDate), 0)
--where ct.minutes between '2016-10-03' and '2016-10-05' if you wanna test on an interval, put what you need here
group by minutes
order by minutes
```

Comment: Still being unfixed. How to increment the field of the following hour for the overflow calls ?
Sample : A call how beging at 01:40 PM and ends at 02:30 PM
Should increment the twenty last field of my "Counting table" and the theerty first field for the hour 02:00-03:00

Comment: Not sure I get it : you want result by minute, not hour ? So for example if a call starts at 19h59 and ends at 20h02, you want a count of 1 for 59-0, 1 for 0-1, and 1 for 1-2, no ? That's what the query (should) do...

Comment: Yeah, that's the way. But the 1 for 0-1 and for 1-2, should increase the first field of the next hour and don't know how to deal with.
The point is to build a diagramme that track and count on each minutes of each hour on each day, the number of alls calls that are running.

Comment: So correct me if I'm wrong : if you've got a call from 21h59 to 22h00, and one from 22h59 to 23h00, you don't want 59-0 = 2, for example, but 21h59-22h00 = 1 and 22h59-23h00 = 1 ?

Comment: Yes, you are right.  The diagrame should start on the first Jun 2015 and show us the number of calls that are made on each minutes (zoomable) 
Example : Between 02 PM and 04 PM we should be able to show the pike time (summit) with the number of calls.
02:01 PM : 5 call running
02:02 PM : 3 call running 
...

Comment: You got it perfectly =)

Comment: So take a look at Edit.

Comment: No idea to be honest, if that's a kind of reporting tool, you should be able to add parameter to your query, but I don't know Biwee at all...

Comment: Thank you Raphaël ! That was a great help