# Inserting individual values into table based on a number

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my problem: I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012 which should do the following thing.

I will pass an input parameter `@Range`, and the stored procedure should insert values into a table starting from 0 to `@Range-1`.

```
CREATE PROC MyExample
     (@Range INT)
AS
BEGIN
   // Suppose the value of @Range is 100
   // So I should do INSERT into MyTable Values(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,......99)
END
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: its seems as a homework and it is really easy , just add insert statement and isnide of it an argument. adding a loop

Comment: So you want to insert at row level or column level.By watching your query it seems you want to insert in that number of columns depending on the range?please clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am thinking your teacher may suspect why you use cte when you just learn a loop

```
CREATE PROC MyExample
(
    @Range INT,
)
AS
BEGIN
    ;WITH numbers AS 
    (  
        SELECT 0 AS Value WHERE @Range >= 0 -- Validate the @Range value too, try 0 or negative values
        UNION ALL SELECT Value + 1 FROM numbers WHERE Value + 1 < @Range
    )
    INSERT INTO MyTable
    SELECT * FROM numbers
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
END
```

Comment: thanks a ton! worked perfectly fine. Will do the valudations for the range as well . Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use **while loop** as below:

```
Declare @Index AS INT=0

WHILE @Index<@Range
BEGIN
    INSERT into MyTable Values(@Index)
    SET @Index=@Index+1
END
```

Comment: Initially thought of going with this...But looking at insert statement of procedure i think insertion need to happen at the column level.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROC MyExample
(
    @Range INT,
)
AS
BEGIN
declare @RANGE_COUNT int

select @RANGE_COUNT =@Range 
   //Suppose the value of @Range is 100
while @RANGE_COUNT<>0
begin
  //So I should do INSERT into MyTable Values(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,......99)
  INSERT into MyTable Values(@Range)
set @RANGE_COUNT = RANGE_COUNT -1
end
END
```

Comment: This suggestion has some flaws... 1. where do you set the initial value of `@RANGE_COUNT`? 2. why is it numeric instead of int? 3, your loop condition is wrong. 4. Your insert is wrong - it will insert 100 each time.

Comment: @ZoharPeled  check now please , as the point 4 its not clear from the OP

Comment: I think it's clear enough - he wants to insert the numbers between 0 and the value of `@Range`. withdrawn my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

And here is a set based approach:

```
CREATE PROC MyExample
(
    @Range INT,
)
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO MyTable (Number)
    SELECT TOP (@Range) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1
    FROM sys.objects s1       
    CROSS JOIN sys.objects s2 
END
```

(Based on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393951/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-and-populate-a-numbers-table))

Answer (score 0):

Using tally table technique:

```
DECLARE @range INT = 100

SELECT TOP(@range) -1 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn 
FROM 
    (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) t1(n) CROSS JOIN --10
    (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) t2(n) CROSS JOIN --100
    (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) t3(n)            --1000
    --...continue to cover all possible @range values
```

Comment: I think the `-1` should be on the `row_number`, since the OP has asked to insert the value `0` as well...