# SQL using while loop to calculate values for multiple elements

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

I am trying to calculate an average daily stock of each item in a warehouse using Ms SQL.
Every incoming and outgoing quantity is recorded in the same column, let's name it [quantity]. Due to this structure the only way for me to tell the stock level for today is to simply **sum all of the quantity from the beginning of time**. 
i.e.

```
SELECT [item], SUM(quantity)
FROM item_table
```

If I want to see the stock level of yesterday I would need to following code:

```
SELECT [item], SUM(quantity)
FROM item_table
WHERE [date] < DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE())
```

And so on for every single day. Of course I'm not going to go through the trouble of manually changing the `DATEADD` number 360 times in order to get the stock level for the entire year. Hence I am using a While loop as follows:

```
DECLARE @intFlag INT
DECLARE @s DECIMAL = 0
DECLARE @i varchar(20) --replaced with table (see table part below)
SET @intFlag = 0
WHILE (@intFlag <= 360)
BEGIN
SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
SET @i = (SELECT TOP (1) [item] FROM item_table ) --replaced with table (see table part below)
SET @s = (
        SELECT
            SUM(quantity) + @s AS inventory
        FROM item_table
        WHERE 
        item IN (@i) --replaced with table (see table part below)
        AND [Date] < dateadd(day, - @intFlag, GETDATE())
        )
IF @intFlag = 360
    BREAK;
END

SELECT 
@i AS [item],
@s/360 AS [AVG_stock]
```

This is working properly so far, but I'm stuck when trying to do the same operation for multiple items.
When I try replacing the `@i` parameter with a table like this:

```
DECLARE @items table (number varchar (20))
INSERT INTO @items 
SELECT DISTINCT [Item]
FROM items_table
```

And try to call it in

```
SET @s = (
        SELECT
            SUM(quantity) + @s AS inventory
        FROM item_table
        WHERE 
        item IN (@items) 
        AND [Date] < dateadd(day, - @intFlag, GETDATE())
        )
```

SQL cannot find the `@item` table and says that it needs to be declared first. At this point I don't know why is this happening and how can I fix it. Also I have my doubts about the performance of that query since there are around 30,000 items that I would perform the stock calculation for.

Maybe there is an easy fix to this problem, or maybe someone can come up with a completely different way of calculating that damned thing. Anyway I could use any help I can get.

Kind Regards.

Comment: Try to replace this part:  ´WHERE item IN (@items)´  with  ´WHERE 
        item IN (SELECT number FROM @items) ´

Comment: WHERE   item IN (SELECT number FROM @items). Can't you just Group by StockItem, Date and then Avg the stockAmount column, add a where clause to limit the date?

Comment: But I can't really get it. You are calculating a SUM() of some item for every day - day by day. Is this not equvalent to calculating SUM() of this item for a whole periode of 360 days? Why are you making it so complicated? You may GROUP BY items that you inserted in your @Items table in the end.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer ! The (SELECT number FROM @items) is quite an obvious solution, can't believe I didn't come up with it before :D ! Unfortunately the performance is terrible as I expected.

Comment: As explained in the post , I can't simply limit the dates because of the way the table is structured. I can't sum the stock 'day by day'. I can only sum the entire value up to a certain day to get a correct amount for that day. If I were to limit it from both sides with date between '' and '' it's gonna cut out previous incoming and outgoing stock quantities returning a wrong amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ALL items, try this:

```
    With Ints(aInt) As
      (Select -365 Union All
       Select aInt + 1 From Ints
       Where aInt < 0)   
    Select item,
       DateAdd(day, i.aInt, getdate()) tdate 
       Sum(quantity) runningTotal
    from item_table it join Ints i
       on it.[Date] < DateAdd(day, i.aInt, getdate()) 
    group by item, DateAdd(day, i.aInt, getdate()) 
    Option (MaxRecursion 1000)
```

to restrict it to some small set of items, just add a where clause

```
    With Ints(aInt) As
      (Select -365 Union All
       Select aInt + 1 From Ints
       Where aInt < 0)   
    Select item,
       DateAdd(day, i.aInt, getdate()) tdate 
       Sum(quantity) runningTotal
    from item_table it join Ints i
       on it.[Date] < DateAdd(day, i.aInt, getdate()) 
    where item in ([set of comma-delimited item values here])
    group by item, DateAdd(day, i.aInt, getdate()) 
    Option (MaxRecursion 1000)
```

Comment: I couldn't get results from this code as im getting the following error when I try to run it : The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion (error 530). Also sql required this code to be grouped by item and the i.aInt column.

Comment: oh yeah I forgot... you have to reset the max recursion level (it defaults to 100).  I modified to add that (and the group by clause)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a cumulative sum.  Even in SQL Server 2008 your `while` loop is not the best approach.  You might as well do the following:

```
SELECT it.item, it2.quantity
FROM item_table it OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT SUM(it2.quantity) as quantity
      FROM it2
      WHERE it2.item = it.item AND
            it2.date < it.date
     ) it2;
```

In this case, the fastest way (apart from upgrading SQL Server) is to do a `while` loop keeping an *incremental* value for each day.  However, that might be challenging because you need to handle a separate variable for each item.

Comment: should it be it2.date <= it.date?

Comment: Hi, this calculation performs great! However I don't know how could I limit it to only calculate  for the past 360 days.

Comment: @Maffa_sql . . . You can put the date condition in a `where` clause in the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

Create a "Numbers" (or "Tally" table).  It is just a single-column table than contains sequential integers.  You can read about how to create one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393951/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-and-populate-a-numbers-table).  They are useful for replacing while loops.

Once you have that, you can do something like this:

```
select i.item, 
i.date, 
sum(i.quantity) over (partition by i.item order by i.date) quantity
from item_table i
join Numbers n on i.date = DATEADD(dd, -1*n.n, convert(date, getdate()))
where n.n <= 365
```

That should give you a running total of your quantity for each day.

[DEMO here](http://rextester.com/FROT52242)