# Generate range of numbers between two numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I could use some help with a query to expand a CSV I'm working with, but I don't know the best way to handle the query.  My data looks like this:

```
ID-Begin | ID-End | Color | Dwelling
-------------------------------------
79000    | 79999  | Red   | Condo
82100    | 82600  | Blue  | House
etc
```

I need to generate a range between the beginning ID and ending ID, and then duplicate the color and dwelling entries for that range.  This is what I'm hoping to achieve:

```
 ID   |  Color  | Dwelling
------------------------
79000 |  Red    | Condo
79001 |  Red    | Condo
79002 |  Red    | Condo
.....
79999 |  Red    | Condo
82100 |  Blue   | House
82101 |  Blue   | House
.....
82600 |  Blue   | House
```

I've see other methods that allow me to generate a single range of numbers, but nothing that pulls the beginning and ending numbers from the columns in a table.

Anyway help is greatly appreciated!!

Storm

Comment: Use an inner join to a numbers table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it with a recursive CTE like this

```
;WITH temp AS
(
   SELECT 1 AS ID 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT t.ID + 1 FROM temp t
   WHERE t.ID < 100000
) -- return table with id from 1 to 100000
SELECT t.ID,  y.Color, y.Dwelling
FROM YourTable y
INNER JOIN temp t ON t.ID BETWEEN y.IdBegin AND y.IdEnd
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
declare @content table ([ID-Begin] int,[ID-End] int,Color char(20),Dwelling char(20))
insert into @content values(79000,79999,'Red' ,'Condo')
insert into @content values(82100,82600,'Blue','House')

;with cte as (
    select [ID-Begin] ,[ID-End] ,Color,Dwelling
    from @content
    union all
    select [ID-Begin]+1,[ID-End],Color,Dwelling
    from cte
    where [ID-Begin]+1<=[ID-End]
    )
    select [Id-Begin],Color,Dwelling from cte order by [ID-Begin] 
    option (maxrecursion 10000)
```

Answer (score 2):

use a Number or Tally table

```
SELECT n.number as ID, t.Color, t.Dwelling
FROM   yourtable t
       INNER JOIN number_table n ON  n.number >= t.ID_Begin
                                 AND n.number <= t.ID_End
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest (and probably best) way to do this is to use a numbers table. If you don't already have a numbers table, read [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393951/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-and-populate-a-numbers-table) on how to create it. If you want to know more about what is a numbers table and why do you want one, read [this blog post](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/) by Jeff Moden.

Once you have a numbers table, all you need is to use an inner join:

```
SELECT Number as Id,
       Color,
       Dwelling
FROM YourTable 
INNER JOIN Numbers ON Number >= [ID-Begin] 
                  AND Number <= [ID-End]
```

Answer (score 1):

Update for SQL 2017 and later: If the sequence you desire is < 8k then this will work:

```
Declare @start_num int = 1000
,   @end_num int = 1050

Select [number] = @start_num + ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (Select null))
from string_split(replicate(' ',@end_num-@start_num-1),' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL-server version is higher than 2022, we can try to use [GENERATE_SERIES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/generate-series-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) with `CROSS APPLY` and let `[ID-Begin]` and `[ID-End]` be `START` and `STOP` parameters and let query be elegant and more efficient.

- START： The START parameter is the first value in the interval. The START parameter is specified as a variable, a literal, or a scalar expression of type `tinyint, smallint, int, bigint, decimal, or numeric`.
- STOP： The STOP parameter is the last value in the interval. The STOP parameter is specified as a variable, a literal, or a scalar expression of type `tinyint, smallint, int, bigint, decimal, or numeric`. The series stops once the last generated step value exceeds the STOP value.

`GENERATE_SERIES` returns a single-column table containing a sequence of values in which each differs from the preceding by `STEP`

> please make sure the `compatibility_level` is right

```
SELECT Id.[Value],
       t1.Color,
       t1.Dwelling
FROM T t1
CROSS APPLY GENERATE_SERIES(START = [ID-Begin], STOP = [ID-End]) Id
```