# While loop inside select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write select statement where in it will iterate through a specific logic while selecting records itself.

```
Start_Date  End_Date
2011-01-01   2011-04-01
```

If I have above record then I need to write to output based on number of months difference between 2 dates. (On every iteration need to increment start_date by one month so that difference will be only months)

Final Output:

```
Start_Date  End_Date  Date_Col
2011-01-01  2011-04-01 2011-01-01
2011-01-01  2011-04-01 2011-02-01
2011-01-01  2011-04-01 2011-03-01
2011-01-01  2011-04-01 2011-04-01
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Recursive WITH support?

Comment: In Postgres you can `generate_series()`

Comment: database is SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution

```
DECLARE @Start_Date DATETIME = '2011-01-01',
        @End_Date DATETIME = '2011-04-01';
WITH DateArray
AS
(SELECT @Start_Date AS DateElement
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD (month, 1, DateElement) FROM DateArray WHERE DateElement < @End_Date
)
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @Start_Date,120) Start_Date,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @End_Date,120) End_Date,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateElement,120) Date_Col
  FROM DateArray;
```

Output is

```
Start_Date  End_Date    Date_Col
2011-01-01  2011-04-01  2011-01-01
2011-01-01  2011-04-01  2011-02-01
2011-01-01  2011-04-01  2011-03-01
2011-01-01  2011-04-01  2011-04-01
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer a numbers table solution over a recursive cte.
There are a couple of benefits to this approach - the main benefit is performance.

If you don't already have a numbers table, you should probably read Jeff Moden's [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/), and also [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393951/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-and-populate-a-numbers-table) on creating a numbers table in SQL Server.

So, once you created the numbers table, it's a simple join:

```
SELECT Start_Date, 
       End_Date, 
       DATEADD(MONTH, Number, Start_Date) As Date_Col
FROM YourTable
JOIN Numbers ON Number <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, Start_Date, End_Date)
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/EPAW87860)