# SQL Active Users by day

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've got a table with `CustomerID`, `StartDate` and `EndDate`.
I'm trying to create a table with the following columns: `Date`, `ActiveUsers`.

The `Date` needs to be all dates between 01/01/2016 and today. `ActiveUsers` is a count of `CustomerID` where the `Date` falls between the `StartDate` and `EndDate`.

I hope all that makes sense.

I found code that gives me a list of dates but I have no idea how I can join my customers table to this result.

```
DECLARE @StartDateTime DATE
DECLARE @EndDateTime DATE

SET @StartDateTime = '2016-01-01'
SET @EndDateTime = GETDATE();

WITH DateRange(DateData) AS 
(
    SELECT @StartDateTime as Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(d,1,DateData)
    FROM DateRange 
    WHERE DateData <= @EndDateTime
)
SELECT dr.DateData
FROM DateRange dr
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) 
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple left join, group by and count:

```
SELECT DateData, COUNT(CustomerID) as ActiveUsers
FROM DateRange AS D
LEFT JOIN Customers AS C 
    ON D.DateData >= C.StartDate 
    AND D.DateData <= C.EndDate
GROUP BY DateData
```

However, here's a free tip: Using a recursive cte for things like that is fine when the range is small, but if you find yourself having to use `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` it means you are in danger of a performance hit because of the recursive cte and should replace it with a tally table based solution.

If you don't know what a tally table is, read Jeff Moden's [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop.](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/)
If you don't already have a tally table, read [What is the best way to create and populate a numbers table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393951/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-and-populate-a-numbers-table)

Having said that, date related queries often benefit from having a pre-populated calendar table - such a table can save you from calculating weekends, national holidays etc', at a storage price that's practically negligible in modern servers. 
Read Aaron Bertrand's [Creating a date dimension or calendar table in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) for a step-by-step explanation on how to create one for yourself.