# How to create a SQL Server table with exactly 1 MB data in it

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'd like to try and gauge my users internet speeds based on the downloading of a dataset of known size (1MB).

Using T-SQL only, how can I quickly create a table with exactly 1MB of data in it?

I want to be able to run `EXEC sp_spaceused N'dbo.myTableName` to verify `data` size.

Comment: You mean like a table with a `VarChar(max)` column and a single row containing 1MB of data?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replicate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 - REPLICATE might be useful. Pay attention to the note. Also consider a CTE and/or a 'numbers table' (easy to add 'N rows', eg).

Comment: there are lots of other way to determine the internet speed. This is not a good way.

Comment: Hi @HABO, Yes, that would work. I do like user2864740's idea of a numbers table.

Squirrel, not in PowerApps there isn't !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to create and populate a numbers table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393951/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-and-populate-a-numbers-table)

Answer (score 0):

The SO search keywords ended up being `Numbers Table`. Searching for *this term*, I found a great post. 
Closing this as duplicate of: [What is the best way to create and populate a numbers table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393951/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-and-populate-a-numbers-table)

I think i'm going to move a different direction for my use case with

`fsutil file createnew C:\Desktop\testFile.png 1000000`