# How to create numbers range of numbers between two numbers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursive-query

So i have  Table and i have Columns NumberMin(minimal number ) and i have NumberMax(maximal number)
i have many records i want to select all data and in new column i had numbers beetwen this number min and number max like this
this is table

```
ID Name NumberMin NumberMax 
13 Jhon 10        14
```

and when i select  i want to  be like this

```
Name NumberMin NumberMax newcolum
Jhon 10        14        10
Jhon 10        14        11
Jhon 10        14        12
Jhon 10        14        13
```

i tried this code but didn't worked  like this

```
;with numcte  
AS  
(  
  SELECT NumbMin as[SEQUENCE]  
  UNION all  
  SELECT Name,NumbMin,NumbMax,[SEQUENCE] + 1 FROM Table WHERE NumbMin  <NumbMax 
)      
SELECT * FROM numcte
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to create and populate a numbers table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393951/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-and-populate-a-numbers-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your query is that both the anchor and the recursive part of the query must have the same number of columns (and identical datatypes). Your anchor has just one column (`numberMin`), while the recursive part has 4 columns, so the query errors.

Consider:

```
with numcte as (
    select id, name, numberMin, numberMax, numberMin newcol from mytable
    union all
    select id, name, numberMin, numberMax, newcol + 1
    from numcte
    where newcol < numberMax - 1
)
select * from numcte
```

The `where` condition prevents the last value of `newcol` to actually reach `numberMax` - that's a bit unusual, but that's what your desired result is showing.

Note that SQL Server by default restricts the number of iteration of a recursive query to 100. If you need to handle more than that, you need to add `option (maxrecursion 0)` at the end of the query.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another option is an ad-hoc tally table.

Not sure if you wanted to exclude the top value (14).  If so, just remove the +1 in the `Select top(...)`

**Example**

```
Select A.* 
      ,NewColumn = NumberMin+B.N-1
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Top (NumberMax-NumberMin+1) N=row_number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) From master..spt_values n1, master..spt_values n2
             ) B
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: @TheImpaler You may be rright.  I did, however, add a "Not sure"

Comment: @TheImpaler Seemed odd that OP has min but not max.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know the table `master..spt_values` existed. Can come in handy.

Comment: @TheImpaler Any table of appropriate size/rows will do.... notice the Order By (Select null)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive CTE to do this.

For example:

```
with
x as (
  select ID, Name, NumberMin, NumberMax, NumberMin as cur from t
  UNION ALL
  select ID, Name, NumberMin, NumberMax, cur + 1
  from x
  where cur < NumberMax - 1
)
select * from x
```

Result:

```
ID  Name  NumberMin  NumberMax  cur
--  ----  ---------  ---------  --- 
13  John         10         14   10
13  John         10         14   11
13  John         10         14   12
13  John         10         14   13
```

See running example at [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7fe9f1b06b22a0d58f9570591c103829).