# Group or split rows by value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a list of person by nationality. These people must be grouped or divided if their number is greater or less than 4 in group of max 4 person with same nationality.

| Nationality | Number |
| --- | --- |
| Italian | 7 |
| Franch | 2 |
| Franch | 3 |
| English | 2 |
| English | 1 |
| Spanish | 9 |

The result that I wont is :

| Nationality | groupOf |
| --- | --- |
| Italian | 4 |
| Italian | 3 |
| franch | 4 |
| franch | 1 |
| English | 3 |
| Spanish | 4 |
| Spanish | 4 |
| Spanish | 1 |

The goal is to get groups of 4 or less. For example if I have 41 rows of Swedish with Number=1 the goal is 10 rows of Swedish with  GroupOf = 4 plus one row with groupOf = 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to multiple (using a [tally/numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393951/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-and-populate-a-numbers-table) table) and number the rows, and then use an additional calculation (with the appropriate grouping):

Sample data and a tally table:

```
SELECT *
INTO Data
FROM (VALUES
   ('Italian', 7),
   ('Franch',  2),
   ('Franch',  3),
   ('English', 2),
   ('English', 1),
   ('Spanish', 9)
) v (Nationality, [Number])
SELECT *
INTO Tally
FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10)) t (Rn)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT Nationality, COUNT(*) AS GroupOf
FROM (
   SELECT Nationality, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.Nationality ORDER BY Nationality) AS Rn
   FROM Data d
   JOIN Tally t ON t.Rn <= d.[Number]
) t
GROUP BY Nationality, ((Rn - 1) / 4)
```

Result:

| Nationality | GroupOf |
| --- | --- |
| English | 3 |
| Franch | 4 |
| Franch | 1 |
| Italian | 4 |
| Italian | 3 |
| Spanish | 4 |
| Spanish | 4 |
| Spanish | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

Another option utilizing a tally/numbers table, is to group first, then explode the rows by joining the tally

```sql
SELECT
  d.Nationality,
  CASE WHEN t.Rn <= (d.GroupOf / 4)
    THEN 4
    ELSE d.GroupOf - ((t.Rn - 1) * 4)
  END AS GroupOf
FROM (
   SELECT Nationality, SUM(d.Number) AS GroupOf
   FROM Data d
   GROUP BY Nationality
) d
JOIN Tally t ON t.Rn <= ((d.GroupOf + 3) / 4);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=09ad86822498f1909a496ee23238ce96)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a recursive CTE:

```
WITH 
  t AS (SELECT Nationality, SUM(Number) total FROM tablename GROUP BY Nationality),
  cte AS (
    SELECT Nationality, 
           total - CASE WHEN total <= 4 THEN total ELSE 4 END total, 
           CASE WHEN total <= 4 THEN total ELSE 4 END groupOf
    FROM t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Nationality, 
           total - CASE WHEN total <= 4 THEN total ELSE 4 END total, 
           CASE WHEN total <= 4 THEN total ELSE 4 END groupOf 
    FROM cte
    WHERE total > 0
  )
SELECT Nationality, groupOf 
FROM cte
ORDER BY Nationality, groupOf DESC
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0); -- remove this line if Numbers are not greater than 400 = 4 * 100
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c4bd203f5313ca66eb6db07e0ab30314).