# fetch the monthnames between two date columns as a concatenated string in a new column

Tags: sql, datetime

Please help to fetch the monthnames between two date columns as a concatenated string in a new column.

[image]

the above image shows my table data..

if the end date is null, we need to take till end of the year

desired output is

[image]
Below find the scripts needed for the table below

```
CREATE TABLE OfferTest(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StartDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [EndDate] [datetime] NULL
) 

insert into OfferTest values(1000,'01/01/2021','05/31/2021') 
insert into OfferTest values(2000,'01/01/2021','05/31/2021') 
insert into OfferTest values(3000,'07/01/2021','09/30/2021') 
insert into OfferTest values(4000,'11/01/2021',NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

First create this number table if you don't have one already

```
SELECT TOP 10000 N=IDENTITY(INT, 0, 1)
INTO dbo.Numbers
FROM master.dbo.syscolumns a CROSS JOIN master.dbo.syscolumns  b;
ALTER TABLE dbo.Numbers ADD CONSTRAINT NBR_pk PRIMARY KEY(N);

;with cte(id, Months) as (
select id, STRING_AGG(format(dateadd(m,n.n,StartDate),'MMM'),',')
from offertest o cross join dbo.Numbers n
where dateadd(m,n.n,StartDate)<=isnull(EndDate, '20211231')
group by id)
select o.StartDate,o.EndDate,c.Months 
from cte c inner join offertest o on o.id=c.id
```

### TEST

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/626e3/1

You can replace '20211231' with `getdate()` or other limit date

### EDIT

You can create the numbers table as a tempt table just by adding #

```
SELECT TOP 10000 N=IDENTITY(INT, 0, 1)
INTO #Numbers
FROM master.dbo.syscolumns a CROSS JOIN master.dbo.syscolumns  b;
ALTER TABLE #Numbers ADD CONSTRAINT NBR_pk PRIMARY KEY(N);
```

Regarding using the query as subquery, there is no need, just use it as a CTE like this:

```
;with cte(id, Months) as (
select id, STRING_AGG(format(dateadd(m,n.n,StartDate),'MMM'),',')
from offertest o cross join #Numbers n
where dateadd(m,n.n,StartDate)<=isnull(EndDate, '20211231')
group by id)
,months(StartDate,EndDate,Months) as (
select o.StartDate,o.EndDate,c.Months 
from cte c inner join offertest o on o.id=c.id)

Select 'your query here joining Months'
```

Comment: is it possible to achieve this without Numbers table...i am not allowed to create tables in the server

Comment: also want to use this as a subquery in a join with another table

Comment: Syscolumns table is not supported....'Reference to database and/or server name in 'master.dbo.syscolumns' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393951/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-and-populate-a-numbers-table

Comment: @PRI did you make it work? if not, just insert numbers from 0 to 20 in the numbers table