# Recursively add dates in Azure Synapse Analytics instead of Max Recursion

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-synapse

In the table MonthCalender, I have added two date ranges and I am trying to insert monthly start and month end dates within the range.

| MonthName | MonthStart | MonthEnd |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Previous Months | 2010-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2023-06-01 08:21:30.813 |
| UpdateValue | 2023-06-01 08:21:30.817 | 2030-01-01 00:00:00.000 |

I want to insert month start and month end dates like this.

| MonthName | MonthStart | MonthEnd |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Previous Months | 2010-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2010-02-01 00:00:00.000 |
| Previous Months | 2010-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2010-03-01 00:00:00.000 |
| Previous Months | 2010-03-01 00:00:00.000 | 2010-04-01 00:00:00.000 |
| Previous Months | 2010-04-01 00:00:00.000 | 2010-05-01 00:00:00.000 |
| Previous Months | 2010-05-01 00:00:00.000 | 2010-06-01 00:00:00.000 |
| Previous Months | 2010-06-01 00:00:00.000 | 2010-07-01 00:00:00.000 |

... till 2023-06-01 00:00:00.000

The Code is using maxrecursion but that is not supported in synapse. How do I use a loop to insert data within the range?

```
;WITH cSequence AS (     
SELECT  'Previous Months' as MonthName, 
  Cast('2010-01-01 00:00:00.000' as datetime) AS StartRange,  
  Cast(DATEADD(m, 1, '2010-01-01 00:00:00.000') as datetime) AS EndRange
UNION ALL     
SELECT  CASE WHEN EndRange >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0) THEN 'UpdateValue' ELSE 'Previous Months' END as MonthName, 
  EndRange,                  
  DATEADD(m, 1, EndRange)
FROM cSequence      
WHERE DATEADD(m, 1, EndRange) < '2030-01-01 00:00:00.000' )  
insert into #MonthCalendar 
SELECT * FROM cSequence 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Comment: Numbers table? …

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393951/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-and-populate-a-numbers-table

Answer (score 1):

In your case I understood that  the use of recursion or `MAXRECURSION` option is not supported, so you can use a loop to insert data within the desired date range.

```sql
DECLARE @StartRange DATETIME = '2010-01-01 00:00:00.000'
DECLARE @EndRange DATETIME = '2023-06-01 00:00:00.000'

WHILE @StartRange < @EndRange
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NextMonthStart DATETIME = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @StartRange)
    INSERT INTO #MonthCalendar (MonthName, MonthStart, MonthEnd)
    VALUES ('Previous Months', @StartRange, @NextMonthStart)

    SET @StartRange = @NextMonthStart
END
```

The loop continues until the `@StartRange` value exceeds the `@EndRange` value. In each iteration, it will calculate the next month's start date by adding 1 month to the current `@StartRange` value.

Then, it inserts a row into the `#MonthCalendar` table with the appropriate values for `MonthName`, `MonthStart`, and `MonthEnd`. As a final step, it will update the `@StartRange` value to the calculated `@NextMonthStart` value to proceed to the next iteration.