# Combining multiple results table into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I wrote this query:

```
DECLARE @Counter INT = 0
DECLARE @startDate DATE = (SELECT startDate FROM Table WHERE ID = 334)
DECLARE @endDate DATE = (SELECT startDate FROM Table WHERE ID = 334)

WHILE @Counter < DATEDIFF(day, @startDate, @endDate)
BEGIN
    SELECT
        DATEADD(day, @counter, @startDate) AS startDate,
        DATEADD(day, @counter+1, @startDate) AS endDate

    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
END
```

I get this result:

| startDate | endDate |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |

| startDate | endDate |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

| startDate | endDate |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 5 | Cell 6 |

I would want it to return:

| startDate | endDate |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |
| Cell 5 | Cell 6 |

Any help would be greatly appreciated

I've tried using Union, stored procedures but i still get each results in different tables

Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU18)

Comment: What version of sql server are you running? Use `SELECT @@VERSION` to see and paste it into your question

Comment: If you're on SQL Server 2022+, you can use [`GENERATE_SERIES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/generate-series-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to get a numbers table. From that, you can generate the necessary rows for the dates. If not in 2022+, research on how to generate number tables a different way (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1393951/243373)).

Comment: Please include your actual attempts

Comment: A set-based query using a tally table instead of loop can return a single result set. With the loop, you need to insert the results of each query into a temp table or table variable (e.g. `INSERT INTO @results SELECT DATEADD(day, @counter, @startDate) AS startDate, DATEADD(day, @counter+1, @startDate) AS endDate` and add add a final SELECT to return all results (e.g. `SELECT startDate, EndDate FROM @results)`

Comment: My first thought would be, why are you doing this? I suspect there is a much better and faster way to do what you need. For a start your start and end dates are set to the same value but I guess that's a typo. Supply some sample data that shows what you are really trying to do and what you expect the results would be based on that same sample. I just think you might be going about this the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of SQL Server you can use `GENERATE_SERIES`.

Otherwise use a virtual numbers table.

```sql
WITH L0 AS (
    SELECT 1 AS n
    FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1) ) v(n)
),
L1 AS (
    SELECT 1 AS n
    FROM L0 a CROSS JOIN L0 b   -- 256 rows
),
L2 AS (
    SELECT 1 AS n
    FROM L1 a CROSS JOIN L1 b   -- 65536 rows
)
SELECT
  DATEADD(day, nums.n - 1, t.startDate) startDate,
  DATEADD(day, nums.n, t.startDate) endDate
FROM Table t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(day, startDate, endDate) + 1)
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS n
    FROM L2
) nums
WHERE t.ID = 334;
```