# Transact-SQL - 12 monthly date ranges starting with current month going back

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm creating a filter for a report that is to include a 13 month rolling report period and each month up to the current month.

Clarification:  This filter is to populate a dropdownlist in an asp.net web report, the label is displayed and the value is passed to the stored proc to be processed.

IE:

13 Month Rolling (VALUE 06/12/2013|05/01/2012)

January (VALUE 01/01/2013|01/31/2013)

February ...

March...
...
June ...

I have the rolling 13 month filter logic:

```
DECLARE @rolling varchar(25)
SET @rolling = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101))
SET @rolling += '|'
SET @rolling += CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),(select dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, getdate())-13, 0)), 101)

SELECT DISTINCT
@rolling as [VALUE], '13 Months Rolling' as [LABEL]
```

but I can't figure out how to get the months up to current month.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to calculate in T-SQL or in the asp.net app?

Comment: Right now I'm trying to do it in t-sql.  But as a last resort I can calculate in the c# codebehind.

Comment: Did you do a search for any possible solutions? This answer came up as my first search. It looks to be exactly what you need:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013348/possible-recursive-cte-query-using-date-ranges

Comment: You want a method to get a single pipe-delimited value that itemizes the previous 13 months?