# T sql group by only column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have below columns and column's data types

```
DailyWorkingHours as Daily (money)
case_completion_hour as casecomp (money)
xdate as month (datetime)
```

I have below query

```
select 
sum(cpw.DailyWorkingHours) as Daily, 
sum(ca.case_completion_hour) / 60 as casecomp, 
DateName( month , DateAdd( month , month(ca.xdate) , 0 ) - 1 ) as month

from reseller_user_profiles rup

join cases c on c.reseller_user_ID=rup.reseller_user_ID
join case_action ca on ca.case_ID=c.case_ID
join tblCaseProjectWorkers cpw on c.reseller_user_ID=cpw.resellerUserID 
join tblCaseProjectsNew cpn on cpn.ID=c.project_ID

group by 
DateName( month , DateAdd( month , month(ca.xdate) , 0 ) - 1 ) 

order by  DateName( month , DateAdd( month , month(ca.xdate) , 0 ) - 1 )
```

If I run the query it returns the data as below

```
Daily (column)  -  casecomp (column)  -  month (column)

1088,00           -  0,3333             -  February

544,00            -  0,3344             -  February

321,00            -  0,3377             -  February

150,00            -  0,3387             -  January

332,00            -  0,3330             -  January

658,00            -  4,3331             -  April
```

Question:

How can I select a query as below result (I want to display 12 months even if the month is empty)

```
Daily (column)  -  casecomp (column)  -  month (column)

150,00            -  0,3387             -  January

332,00            -  0,3330             -  

1088,00           -  0,3333             -  February

544,00            -  0,3344             -  

321,00            -  0,3377             -  

NULL              -  NULL               -  March

658,00            -  4,3331             -  April

NULL              -  NULL               -  May

NULL              -  NULL               -  June

NULL              -  NULL               -  July

NULL              -  NULL               -  August

NULL              -  NULL               -  September

NULL              -  NULL               -  October

NULL              -  NULL               -  November

NULL              -  NULL               -  December
```

Month column grouping by inside of month column in result query. What to change in my query code according to achieve this?

Comment: There's two things going on here.  1) You need a listing of months somewhere without it you can't get your months with null values.  This can be derived by a a recursive common table expression to get you the 12 months like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013348/possible-recursive-cte-query-using-date-ranges)  2) using an `over partition by row num  grouping by month` and a `case statement` to give you months populated only when the row num is 1 within the series.

Comment: thanks for your time if you can share code example i will apply on my side and will accept best answer thanks again

Comment: [Example for only displaying first month](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6368/how-to-select-the-first-row-of-each-group) and [Example for getting null values by using a CTE to get all 12 months](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013348/possible-recursive-cte-query-using-date-ranges)  Try incorporating those and if you have trouble post what you've tried, I'm sure you'll get help.  But few will want to write this for you without showing some effort of incorporation

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

```
    CREATE TABLE #Months (Num int, Name varchar(15))

    INSERT INTO #Months SELECT 1, 'January'
    INSERT INTO #Months SELECT 2, 'February'
    INSERT INTO #Months SELECT 3, 'March'
    INSERT INTO #Months SELECT 4, 'April'
    INSERT INTO #Months SELECT 5, 'May'
    INSERT INTO #Months SELECT 6, 'June'
    INSERT INTO #Months SELECT 7, 'July'
    INSERT INTO #Months SELECT 8, 'August'
    INSERT INTO #Months SELECT 9, 'September'
    INSERT INTO #Months SELECT 10, 'October'
    INSERT INTO #Months SELECT 11, 'November'
    INSERT INTO #Months SELECT 12, 'December'


    SELECT *
    FROM 
        #Months m
        LEFT JOIN 
            (
            select 
            sum(cpw.DailyWorkingHours) as Daily, 
            sum(ca.case_completion_hour) / 60 as casecomp, 
            DateName( month , DateAdd( month , month(ca.xdate) , 0 ) - 1 ) as month

            from reseller_user_profiles rup

            join cases c on c.reseller_user_ID=rup.reseller_user_ID
            join case_action ca on ca.case_ID=c.case_ID
            join tblCaseProjectWorkers cpw on c.reseller_user_ID=cpw.resellerUserID 
            join tblCaseProjectsNew cpn on cpn.ID=c.project_ID

            group by 
            DateName( month , DateAdd( month , month(ca.xdate) , 0 ) - 1 ) 


            ) yours
            ON yours.month = m.Name
ORDER BY m.Num
```

Comment: This will not work since you can't use an `order by` clause inside a derived table or a sub query without specifying `top` also. Another problem is that you assume English names to the months. if the user decides to work with another language, your join will break.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
;with Months as (
  select 1 As Months_Number, 
         DateName(month, '2015-01-01') As Months_Name
  UNION ALL
  select Months_Number + 1 , DateName(month, DateAdd(month, Months_Number, '2015-01-01')) As Months_Name
  FROM Months
  WHERE Months_Number < 12
)

select 
sum(cpw.DailyWorkingHours) as Daily, 
sum(ca.case_completion_hour) / 60 as casecomp, 
Months_Name

from Months 
left join (
    reseller_user_profiles rup
    join cases c on c.reseller_user_ID=rup.reseller_user_ID
    join case_action ca on ca.case_ID=c.case_ID
    join tblCaseProjectWorkers cpw on c.reseller_user_ID=cpw.resellerUserID 
    join tblCaseProjectsNew cpn on cpn.ID=c.project_ID) on month(ca.xdate) = Months_Number 

group by Months_Name
order by Months_Name
```

Points of interest:

- the recursive `CTE` gives you a count from 0 to 11. This enables a simple and accurate `left join` condition. (see my comment to EarlOfEnnui's answer)
- the recursive `CTE` also gives you the month names. this allows for a simpler `group by` and `order by` clauses.
- the `left join` of the `CTE` is with all of your other tables (note that there are parenthesis covering all other tables