# Populate all dates between 2 fields in SQL

Tags: sql, calendar, recursive-query

I have a table like this in SQL:

| OrderNumber | From | To |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2018-01-28 | 2018-02-01 |
| 576 | 2018-02-10 | 2018-02-12 |
| 335 | 2018-02-27 | 2018-03-01 |

How to get my table to populate the dates between From and To dates like this?

| OrderNumber | From | To | DailyDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2018-01-28 | 2018-02-01 | 2018-01-28 |
| 123 | 2018-01-28 | 2018-02-01 | 2018-01-29 |
| 123 | 2018-01-28 | 2018-02-01 | 2018-01-30 |
| 123 | 2018-01-28 | 2018-02-01 | 2018-01-31 |
| 123 | 2018-01-28 | 2018-02-01 | 2018-02-01 |
| 576 | 2018-02-10 | 2018-02-12 | 2018-02-10 |
| 576 | 2018-02-10 | 2018-02-12 | 2018-02-11 |
| 576 | 2018-02-10 | 2018-02-12 | 2018-02-12 |
| 335 | 2018-02-27 | 2018-03-01 | 2018-02-27 |
| 335 | 2018-02-27 | 2018-03-01 | 2018-02-28 |
| 335 | 2018-02-27 | 2018-03-01 | 2018-03-01 |

I'm not sure how to get the dates to populate partitioned by order#. Appreciate any help / ideas!

I've tried the following but get an Invalid Object Name 'PatientDays' error

```
SELECT PatientDays.OrderNumber,
       [Date] = DATEADD(DAY, T.N, PatientDays.From)
FROM (
    SELECT N = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1
    FROM sys.objects
) AS T
JOIN PatientDays AS PatientDays
    ON DATEDIFF(DAY, PatientDays.From, PatientDays.To) >= T.N;
```

Comment: MySql <> SqlServer, I've removed the conflicting tags, please add the tag for the DBMS you are actually using. Look up *Calendar table* which you can out-join with.

Comment: sql server 2022 has now generate_series, for older Version you find here a lot of samples

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Possible recursive CTE query using date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013348/possible-recursive-cte-query-using-date-ranges)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out :D

Had to add my CTE into temp tables

```
select * into #PatientDays

from PatientDays

 

SELECT N = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1

into #T

FROM sys.objects

 

SELECT p.AccountNumber,

       [Date] = DATEADD(DAY, #T.N, p.RegistrationDateTime)

          ,p.RegistrationDateTime

          ,p.LastRegDateTime

FROM #T

JOIN #PatientDays AS p

    ON DATEDIFF(DAY, p.RegistrationDateTime, p.LastRegDateTime) >= #T.N;
```