# What is the best way to select current months dates in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get a list of dates between two dates using a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378593/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-using-a-function)

I need to get the result as

```
1/01/2011
2/01/2011
3/01/2011
4/01/2011
5/01/2011
.
.
.
31/01/2011
```

I don't want to create a table for this. just want to get this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
  DECLARE @startDate DATETIME;
  SET @startDate = CAST(DATEPART(YYYY,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + CAST(DATEPART(M,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '01';

  ;WITH CTE(n) AS
  (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT n+1 FROM CTE WHERE n < 30)
  SELECT    DATEADD(dd,n,@startDate)
  FROM  CTE
  WHERE MONTH(DATEADD(dd,n,@startDate)) = MONTH(@startDate);
```