# Print out all dates between 2 dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

If I have 2 days `2013-06-03` and `2013-06-10` as examples, how do I print a list of all the dates between those 2 dates?

For example, the list in this case would be:

```
2013-06-22
2013-06-23
2013-06-24
2013-06-25
2013-06-26
2013-06-27
2013-06-28
2013-06-29
2013-06-30
2013-07-01
2013-07-02
2013-07-03
2013-07-04
2013-07-05
2013-07-06
2013-07-07
```

Comment: This seems to be answered here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1378788/2429205 let me know if I am wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Start date = '2013-06-03'
DECLARE @End date = '2013-06-10'

;WITH Dates AS 
(
    SELECT @Start AS [Date]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date])
    FROM Dates
    WHERE [Date] < @End
)

SELECT [Date] 
FROM Dates
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: I prefer this solution over the duplicate link solutions!  Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

I think you are looking for this:

> SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE DATE_COLUMN_NAME BETWEEN '03-JUNE-2013' AND '10-JUNE-2013'

Comment: This pre-supposes that you have a table pre-populated with every date between the two points, which I suspect the OP does not have (but which is not a bad idea).