# How to list all dates between two dates

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I would like list dates between two date in a SQL Server stored procedure.

For example:

```
Date1: 2015-05-28
Date2: 2015-05-31
```

Results :

```
2015-05-29
2015-05-30
```

How to calculate all dates between two given dates?

Regards,

Comment: http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3

Answer (score 49):

You can use a numbers table:

```
DECLARE @Date1 DATE, @Date2 DATE
SET @Date1 = '20150528'
SET @Date2 = '20150531'

SELECT DATEADD(DAY,number+1,@Date1) [Date]
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE type = 'P'
AND DATEADD(DAY,number+1,@Date1) < @Date2
```

Results:

```
╔════════════╗
║    Date    ║
╠════════════╣
║ 2015-05-29 ║
║ 2015-05-30 ║
╚════════════╝
```

Comment: I wouldn't do that. what if I don't have access to `master`?

Comment: @LuisLL That's just a quick example of a numbers table, op could use any other one, or a calendar table. It is typically faster than a recursive CTE (though I like to use them, I know they bring performance issues)

Comment: Has limitation if you need to get a long date range... like 15-20 years. Since it is using table master..spt_values

Comment: Not bulletproof since the values range from `spt_values` is limited to 0-2047.

Comment: It is the best solution for most people, it's short and generates less noise, even if it is not the most general. That being said, one might wonder why generating a list of numbers/dates is so difficult with SQL...

Answer (score 34):

Use this,

```
DECLARE @start_date DATETIME = '2015-02-12 00:00:00.000';
DECLARE @end_date DATETIME = '2015-02-13 00:00:00.000';

WITH    AllDays
          AS ( SELECT   @start_date AS [Date], 1 AS [level]
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date]), [level] + 1
               FROM     AllDays
               WHERE    [Date] < @end_date )
     SELECT [Date], [level]
     FROM   AllDays OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

pass the **@start_date** and **@end_date** as SP parameters.

**Result:**

```
Date                    level
----------------------- -----------
2015-02-12 00:00:00.000 1
2015-02-13 00:00:00.000 2

(2 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: It works perfectly but I cant grasp an understanding on how it works, do you have a link for reference? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 20):

Create a stored procedure that does something like the following:

```
declare @startDate date;
declare @endDate date;

select @startDate = '20150528';
select @endDate = '20150531';

with dateRange as
(
  select dt = dateadd(dd, 1, @startDate)
  where dateadd(dd, 1, @startDate) < @endDate
  union all
  select dateadd(dd, 1, dt)
  from dateRange
  where dateadd(dd, 1, dt) < @endDate
)
select *
from dateRange
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/16744).

Or better still create a calendar table and just select from that.

Comment: I think that every database should have a calendar table

Comment: Consider `option (maxrecursion 32767)`

Answer (score 1):

I made a calendar using:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22776.t-sql-calendar-table.aspx

then a Store procedure passing two dates and thats all:

```
USE DB_NAME;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_LISTAR_RANGO_FECHAS]
@FEC_INICIO date,
@FEC_FIN date
AS
Select Date from CALENDARIO where Date BETWEEN @FEC_INICIO AND @FEC_FIN;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a stored procedure passing 2 dates

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SELECTALLDATES
(
@StartDate as date,
@EndDate as date
)
AS
Declare @Current as date = DATEADD(DD, 1, @BeginDate);

Create table #tmpDates
(displayDate date)

WHILE @Current < @EndDate
BEGIN
insert into #tmpDates
VALUES(@Current);
set @Current = DATEADD(DD, 1, @Current) -- add 1 to current day
END

Select * 
from #tmpDates

drop table #tmpDates
```