# SQL Server count message per day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server and I have the following table:

```
tbl_Message:
id, date, group_id
```

Which is a table containing messages: it's id, the date it was sent, the group it was sent in.
I'm trying to calculate the number of messages received every day. I made a query for it but it doesn't return days with no messages. The query is:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, date)/1440 * 1440,0) AS dateDay,
COUNT(*) AS countMsgDay
FROM tbl_Message
WHERE group_id = 1
GROUP BY DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, date)/1440 * 1440,0)
```

Example:

For tbl_Message

```
id |     date                 | group_id
----------------------------------------
1  | 2014-10-01 21:04:00.000  | 1
2  | 2014-10-03 21:09:00.000  | 1
```

The query returns:

```
dateDay                    | countMsgDay
---------------------------------
2014-10-01 00:00:00.000    | 1
2014-10-03 00:00:00.000    | 1
```

and what I want is:

```
dateDay                    | countMsgDay
---------------------------------
2014-10-01 00:00:00.000    | 1
2014-10-02 00:00:00.000    | 0
2014-10-03 00:00:00.000    | 1
```

Comment: You are going to need a way to generate data for the missing days.  One option would be a date table, which you could add to your schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this link to generate dates between your given dates. Use start_date as `min(dateDay)` and end_date as `max(dateDay)`

[How to list all dates between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529860/how-to-list-all-dates-between-two-dates)

Now use this table and join with your query. Say table to derive table is `dateRange`. So `select * from dateRange` will generate date from `2014-10-01` to `2014-10-03`.

Now use a query like below to get the desired output

```
select dr.dateval,t.countMsgDay
from dateRange dr
left join
(
    SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, date)/1440 * 1440,0) AS dateDay,
    COUNT(*) AS countMsgDay
    FROM tbl_Message
    WHERE group_id = 1
    GROUP BY DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, date)/1440 * 1440,0)
) t
on dr.dateval=t.dateDay
```

Answer (score 1):

The normal solution to this problem is to generate all days of data and then use a `left join`.  You can generate the days in several ways:

- Using a calendar table.
- Using recursive CTEs.
- Using a numbers table.
- Explicitly including the dates in the query.

In some cases, there is a simpler solution which is conditional aggregation.  This assumes that there is at least one record for each day.  Then, you can use conditional aggregation for this purpose:

```
SELECT CAST(date as DATE) as dateDay,
       SUM(CASE WHEN group_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as countMsgDay
FROM tbl_Message
GROUP BY CAST(date as DATE)
ORDER BY dateDay;
```

This will work for you, *assuming that each day has at least one record in the table*.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a calendar table ,once you have that ,all you need to do is use left join with this table to get all dates.There are many [use cases to calendar table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dwainsql/2014/03/30/calendar-tables-in-t-sql/) other than this

EX:

```
select 
DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, date)/1440 * 1440,0) AS dateDay,
COUNT(*) AS countMsgDay
from 
Calendar c
left join
yourtable t
on t.date=c.date
and group_id = 1
GROUP BY DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, date)/1440 * 1440,0)
```