# Restrict the start and end date parameters per selected year parameter

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have requirement where I need to allow the user to select at any time for 1 year worth of data and  restrict the user to select start and end dates within the year selected in year parameter?

Any insight would really help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can **build a custom dataset** based on your requirements (*year parameter, one year limit* etc) and instead of using date parameter, use text parameter and drop down list to values for date selection. Make sense?

And to build a custom dataset, you can use help from the following answer:

[How to list all dates between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17529962/4302116)

Comment: how can I create start and end dated dataset per select year?... each year have 365 days... displaying 365 days as drop down list is not make much sense..

Comment: Correct but so far I'm unable to find another way to do that. let's wait for some other answer? Or I'll try alternatives in spare time.

Answer (score 0):

First create a parameter (begdate)as Data Type: Date/Time and populate the available values, Label as YYYY and Value dd/mm/yyyy - (1st of the 1st month for each year)
Example below:
[image]

In your dataset query you can reference this user selected parameter by inserting a HAVING clause:

for example:

HAVING (tbl_XYZ.AdmissionDate BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, @begdate), 0) AND DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, @begdate) + 1, - 1))

Comment: user can search the data for any year... as years changes new years adding up... so specify the values is not an option for me

Comment: Would it be more useful to select/input a start date and the report then automatically equates the end date as +365days (even if it crosses into the next year?)