# Add column with filled days between start_date and end_date

Tags: sql, hadoop, impala

I have input table with this structure:

```
acct_id pvt_data_id pvt_pref_ind start_dttm end_dttm load_dttm pr_load_time
4174878 26  Y   20101126144142  99991231235959  20170527000000  2017052700
4174878 26  Y   20101126144142  99991231235959  20170528000000  2017052800
4174878 26  Y   20101126144142  99991231235959  20170530000000  2017053000
3212472 26  X   20131016144142  99991231235959  20170531000000  2017053100
4174878 26  Y   20101126144142  99991231235959  20170601000000  2017060100
3212472 26  X   20091201142148  99991231235959  20170602000000  2017060200
```

Im supposed to take this table and create a new one with additional column `pr_day`, which would have the integer value of one day (e.g `20170814`) in the range between `start_dttm` and `end_dttm`, so there will be one row for each day within the range.
I started with following query to get the range for each group (consisting of the first 3 columns)

```
select 
acct_id, 
pvt_data_id,
pvt_pref_ind,
cast(min(substr(cast(start_dttm as string),1,8)) as bigint),
max(case when end_dttm=99991231235959 then cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(now()),'yyyyMMdd') as bigint) when end_dttm is null then cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(now()),'yyyyMMdd') as bigint)  else end_dttm end )  

from table1
group by  acct_id, pvt_data_id,pvt_pref_ind
```

Note: values 99991231235959 or null means current day should be used as end_date.
Now Im not sure how to continue, searching guided me towards making a cross join to fill the dates, but what should I join the table to?

Desired output would like this:

```
acct_id pvt_data_id pvt_pref_ind start_dttm end_dttm load_dttm pr_load_time pr_day
4174878 26  Y   20101126144142  99991231235959  20170527000000  2017052700 20101126
4174878 26  Y   20101126144142  99991231235959  20170528000000  2017052800 20101127
4174878 26  Y   20101126144142  99991231235959  20170529000000  2017052900 20101128
4174878 26  Y   20101126144142  99991231235959  20170530000000  2017053000 20101129
3212472 26  X   20131016144142  99991231235959  20170531000000  2017053100 20091202
4174878 26  Y   20101126144142  99991231235959  20170601000000  2017060100 20101130
3212472 26  X   20091201142148  99991231235959  20170602000000  2017060200 20091201¨
```

Thanks for tips and help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to create a work table that lists all of the dates, and then just join your original table to that work table. Getting a list of dates between two dates is discussed in a Stack overflow article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529860/how-to-list-all-dates-between-two-dates), and we only have to tweak that slightly to get it to work for you. For the sake of the answer I'll assume you plan on creating a new table so I'll be selecting the results into a temp table which you can change to be your output table:

```
DECLARE @Date1 DATE, @Date2 DATE
SET @Date1 = (select left(min(start_dttm), 8) from Your_Table) --'20150528'
SET @Date2 = getdate()

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(DAY,number,@Date1), 112) + '000000' as [LongDate]
, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(DAY,number,@Date1), 112) [Shortdate]
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE type = 'P'
AND DATEADD(DAY,number,@Date1) <= @Date2
```

Then you just join the new date range table against your original table on a between clause with the long date value using the short date value to populate the column, something like:

```
#daterange.longdate between YourTable.start_dttm and YourTable.end_dttm
```

Hope that helps,

Comment: thanks for providing me, Ill test it and let you know!